# Quando usar método mágico __contructor ou set e get?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, propriedade, getters-setters

Minha dúvida é com relação construtor, por exemplo, tenho uma classe com `nome`, `idade`. O correto é usar `__construtor` para passar valores a eles ou usar `set` e `get`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que responder se ter esses dados inicializados na instância da classe são fundamentais para considerá-la consistente desde o seu início.

[A função do construtor é criar uma instância em um estado válido desde o início](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), ou seja, não deixar ter acesso até que todos os dados importantes sejam inicializados.

Eu vou acreditar que neste caso esses dois dados são necessários e portanto devem ser inicializados pelo construtor.

Mesmo assim nada impede de ter *setters* e *getters* para eles também, principalmente *getter* que faz algo diferente do que o construtor faz. Assim como mesmo tendo *setter* nada impede de usar a propriedade referente a ele no construtor, mesmo que ele não seja fundamental. É mais comum colocar nos construtores as propriedades essenciais para a classe mas também há casos que pode-se colocar propriedades extras no construtor para facilitar a vida do programador usuário da classe.

Mas se pesquisar aqui, [nem sempre eles devem ser usados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: se eu passar os dados no momento da instanciação da class, posso evitar de usar set se eu quiser, isso ?

Comment: Pode, claro, se estes dados não precisam ser alterados depois, não só pode como deve evitar seu uso.

Comment: Mais uma pergunta. Posso passar função da própria classe no construtor ? ex public function ____construct($nome, geraIdade()), é permitido fazer isso ?

Comment: Não pode porque a declaração do construtor ou qualquer função ou método só permite ter parâmetros. Não pode executar nada. Mas você pode fazer isto dentro corpo do construtor sob certas circunstâncias. Às vezes me confundo com o que pode em cada linguagem, não me lembro bem do PHP mas acho que só poderia chamar métodos estáticos da classe, afinal se for chamar um método que depende da instância inicializada o que ainda não aconteceu dentro do construtor. Só não garanto porque o PHP faz uma maluquices que ninguém consegue explicar. Método estáticos não teria porque impedir. Teste e veja por si.

Comment: ok, mto obrigado. Perguntei isso pq tenho um atributo que necessita ser instanciado no construtor, um gerador de id único, dai estou tentando resolver isso.

Comment: mas posso dentro do construtor chamar um método que retorna um valor para um atributo, sem referência-lo nos parâmetros ?

Comment: ex.: ... ' __construct($val){ $this->atr1 = $val; $this->atr2 = geraValor(); } '

Comment: Conforme eu lhe disse se esse `geraValor()` for estático, pode. Ou se ele for externo a esta classe. Mas também como eu disse, estou me baseando em linguagens decentes. Como o PHP é a linguagem *mainstream* mais mal planejada que eu já vi, pode até ser que ele permita chamar qualquer coisa indiscriminadamente jogando no lixo a vantagem do construtor que é não permitir acesso à instância até que ela esteja completa.

Comment: blz, entend. obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Quando está em dúvida, testa. Quando tiver problema, posta aqui. Se acha que tem erro mesmo funcionando, também.

Comment: testei e funcionou, mas fiquei na dúvida se isso é correto