# Como usar a 9º regra de Object Calisthenics no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, estilo-de-codificação, getters-setters

*Object Calisthenics* fazendo uma tradução para o português significa "exercícios de programação" , e é composto por 9 regras criadas por Jeff Bay em seu livro [The ThoughtWorks Anthology](https://pragprog.com/book/twa/thoughtworks-anthology).

O *Object Calisthenics* é uma série de boas práticas e regras de programação que foram criadas pela comunidade de desenvolvedores Java. Minha dúvida leva em relação apenas a 9º regra e, em resumo, diz que:

> 9. *No Getters/Setters/Properties*: o uso dos métodos acessadores somente devem ser utilizados para obter o estado de um objeto, desde que você não use o resultado para tomar decisões fora do objeto. Pois, qualquer decisão baseada inteiramente no estado de um objeto deve ser feita dentro do próprio objeto. O uso de *Getters/Setters/Properties* também violam o princípio aberto / fechado do *SOLID*

Todo esse conceito foi baseado [aqui](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#no-getterssettersproperties).

O que me deixou um pouco confuso é que usar métodos acessadores é considerado boas práticas de programação. Gostaria de maiores informações e exemplo práticos, se possível, de como poderei implementar a 9° regra voltado para o PHP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Introdução sobre boas práticas

Onde está dizendo que usar *getters* e *setters* é boa prática de programação? Quem disse? Qual a confiabilidade e relevância disto? E mesmo que tenha algo assim, o que boa prática quer dizer? Nada!

Em geral é só a opinião de alguém dizendo para você o que deve fazer em algo que ele nem conhece com o que você está trabalhando. Então a primeira coisa que deve fazer é abandonar essa ideia de boa práticas de programação ou qualquer outra coisa.

Aprenda como as coisas funcionam, aprofunde-se, saiba como é cada mecanismo, técnica, conceito, metodologia, etc. em cada detalhe. Saiba os fundamentos. Entenda porque alguém fala alguma coisa. O que está por trás disso. Será que ela fala com propriedade? Será que só quer vender livro, palestra, curso, consultoria, etc.? Ela é tendenciosa? O que não é de todo ruim, mas é preciso saber quem ela é para avaliar melhor o que está sendo dito. Ela está falando dentro de um contexto específico? O que ela diz resolve um problema e causa outro? Lá explica em profundidade qual o motivo daquilo?

É preciso ter um pensamento crítico de tudo que recebemos, não podemos tomar nada como verdade absoluta. O que lê aqui no site é avaliado por várias pessoas, mesmo assim não quer dizer que seja o certo ou o melhor para você.

Boa prática só serve como dica para estudar mais sobre o assunto.

## Como lidar com esse problema

Eu tenho três visões sobre o assunto.

A que mais gosto é: **se não tem vantagem alguma em ter esses métodos pra que criá-los?**

Em PHP é comum não ter muitas vantagens porque ela é uma linguagem de *script*, então a vinculação do seu uso é feito na hora sempre, *scripts* nunca são sistemas absurdamente complexos. Em outras linguagens eu pensaria o que fazer, em PHP eu usaria quase sempre o atributo direto até que tenha um motivo para mudar. É mais simples, é mais eficiente, ainda que para PHP, eficiência não importa. Quando precisar mudar posso fazer uso de [métodos mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101).

Sei que algumas pessoas usam PHP como linguagem *enterprise* hoje em dia. Acho isso um erro, mas aí faz sentido usar o mecanismo, só não faz sentido a decisão pela ferramenta.

A outra visão é que **você precisa se precaver em ter o método já disponível se um dia precisar incluir um processamento no acesso ou mutação do estado na classe**. Eu acho válido, mas não gosto muito.

É mais válido em Java, por exemplo, onde o vínculo ocorre na compilação. Essa parece ser a que aprendeu. Muitas pessoas acham que isso é encapsulamento, é uma forma, mas não todo ele.

Tem casos que você tem que fazer isso para virtualizar o acesso ao campo, o que é fundamental para determinado mecanismo funcionar. Muito comum entre os ORMs, o que até critico um pouco esse abuso. Nem falei das classes anêmicas que trabalham essencialmente com estado.

A última visão é a mais estrita de orientação a objeto onde diz que **cada método deve ter uma função definida, deve fazer algo próprio, deve ter uma operação que realmente manipule o objeto e não um ponto específico do objeto**. Se a pessoa quer ser "o mais certo" possível, então deve seguir isto.

Conceitualmente a citação postada na pergunta está correta, pelo menos em parte, métodos usar *getters* e *setters* é o caminho fácil para deixar o objeto ser modificado ou acessado.

Lá está escrito:

> você deve **dizer** para a classe fazer algo, não deve **pedir** para ela fazer algo por você

Isso quer dizer que não deve usar mecanismos e sim abstrações. Diga o que quer, não diga como quer.

Uma parte está errada porque se o campo só deve ser modificado ou acessado pelo próprio objeto então não tem porque ter *getters* e *setters*, faça tudo no próprio objeto. Não haverá vínculos externos, refatorar algo interno é sempre muito fácil. Então já questiono se quem escreveu isso pensou bem sobre o assunto.

## Voltando às regras cegas

Por fim, sou contra quase todas essas regras, especialmente por serem regras de ouro para serem seguidas cegamente. Tem regra aí que chega ser completamente absurda, se alguém seguir terá um monstro em mãos. Não sou contra conhecê-las, sou contra não questioná-las.

[image: Martelo dourado batendo em um parafuso]

## Conclusão

[Respondi recentemente sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219409/101) e coloquei exemplos em [diversas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212307/101). Leia tudo sobre o assunto. Entenda porque tecnicamente e conceitualmente esses métodos precisam existir, e porque eles podem ser evitados pelos pragmáticos.

Não deixe o saldo ser alterado, faça uma operação que altere o saldo como consequência. Não deixe alterar o nome da pessoa, permita que ela tenha o nome autorizado de mudar por decisão judicial, ou que tenha uma alteração contratual. Determine uma ação que faça o atributo ser modificado.

Isso é preciosismo? Pode criar mais complicações que soluções? Torna o código inchado? Cria novas necessidades de gerenciamento de manutenção? Sim. Mas também pode ser a melhor solução em casos específicos.

O segredo é dosar bem, e isso só se faz quando não se segue regras, mas se aprende porque as coisas existem. Nem todo abuso é necessariamente ruim.

Um exemplo real com requisitos reais faria você pensar em como implementar corretamente algo. Abstratamente fica só a ideia.

Esse Object Calisthenics especificamente eu acho uma das maiores bobagens que já apareceram na internet, fico pensando se não foi um *hoax* que foi longe demais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Confesso que foi uma das leituras mais esclarecedoras que já tive sobre `getters e setters`. Não só a publicação mais também os links. Confesso que o único conceito que eu tinha sobre os métodos acessadores eram apenas opiniões de outros dizendo que o melhor é usar. Mas, graças a sua resposta mudei de opinião. Abriu minha mente para os questionamentos. Obrigado pela ótima explicação.

Comment: Ótimo, você não sabe como fico feliz com isso.