# Erro PHP POO Polimorfismo

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Ao desenvolver uma simples aplicação PHP POO, me deparei com um erro inesperado, e que eu não tenho a mínima ideia do porque. Eu estou começando agora a estudar programação orientada a objetos e só tenho uma pequena base em C#.

O programa em si é simples: duas classes (`Pessoa` e `Funcionario`) sendo `Funcionario` herdado da classe `Pessoa`, cada uma com 2 métodos, `ler()`e `mostrarDados()`.

O meu objetivo é simples criar um objeto e passar por referencia todas as informações para o metodo `lerDados()` da classe `Funcionario`, e dentro deste, chamar o método `LerDados()` da classe `Pessoa` (`parent::lerDados()`) passando somente as informações relevantes da classe (`nome`, `idade` e `sexo`), os demais é "lido" na própria classe `Funcionario` (`empresa` e `salario`).

> **Erro:** *Declaration of Funcionario::lerDados($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo, $stringEmpresa, $stringSalario) should be compatible with Pessoa::lerDados($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo) in C:\wamp64\www\POO\namespace1.php on line 31*

```
  <?php
  class Pessoa{     
  // PROPRIEDADES
  protected $nome;
  protected $idade;
  protected $sexo;  
  // METODOS      
   public function lerDados($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo){
    $this->nome  = $stringNome;
    $this->idade = $stringIdade;
    $this->sexo  = $stringSexo; 
  }  
  public function mostrarDados(){
    return "Nome: ".$this->nome."<br>\nIdade:".$this->idade."
  <br>\nSexo:".$this->sexo;
  }
  } 


  class Funcionario extends Pessoa{ 
  // PROPRIEDADES
  protected $empresa;
  protected $salario;
  // METODOS    
   public function lerDados($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo, 
   $stringEmpresa, $stringSalario){
     $this->nome  = $stringNome;
     $this->idade = $stringIdade;
     $this->sexo  = $stringSexo; 
     parent:: lerDados($this->nome,$this->idade,$this->sexo); // CHAMAR METODO DAS CLASSE PAI 
     $this->empresa = $stringEmpresa;
     $this->salario = $stringSalario;     
   }
   //public function mostrarDados(){}

   } // <------ERRO NESTA LINHA <-------

   $vendedor = new Funcionario();
   $vendedor->lerDados("Yuri", "19", "Masculino", "Tam", "3000");
   ?>
```

Será que sou eu que estou errando seriamente, ou o PHP não aceita esse tipo de polimorfismo? Alguém poderia me orientar a como arrumar isso, e responder o porquê de acontecer este erro brutalmente fatal?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu costumo dizer que se todo mundo que diz fazer OOP fizesse certo, desistiria. OOP adiciona complexidade ao código. Se feito onde precisa traz vantagens.

Vejo alguns problemas nesse código. Primeiro acho que não cabe herança aí. Há quem discorde, mas acho que ser funcionário é só um [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) que a pessoa pode ter e não há uma [relação de **é um**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

Esse `mostraDados()` pressupõe o uso de um dispositivo específico para mostrar que não deveria fazer parte de uma pessoa ou funcionário. O que é impressão de dados deveria estar em outro lugar.

Quase sempre colocar membros protegidos é um erro. Tem quem ache que as linguagens nem deveriam ter isso porque ou é mal usado ou é para fazer gambiarra. Em geral viola o encapsulamento. Ou é público ou é privado. Vejo motivos para usar, mas não esse.

E aí o `lerDados()` do `Funcionario` ficou esquisito porque ele inicializar os membros protegidos e chama o método da classe mãe para inicializar de novo (?!?!?!).

Esse método não lê dado algum, portanto o nome dele está errado.

[Objetos deveriam ser sempre criados em estado válido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), portanto isto provavelmente deveria ser um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101). Feito dessa forma tudo ficará ok.

Polimorfismo ocorre com [métodos de mesma assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Então o método de uma classe não é polimórfica em relação ao da outra. PHP não possui sobrecarga de métodos e por isso impede que existam dois métodos com mesmo nome e assinatura diferente. Se a assinatura fosse a mesma aí seria polimórfico e a classe filha teria apenas um método com o mesmo nome.

Note que isso não é exatamente o [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154428/101) mesmo em C# e outras linguagens, a diferença é que outras linguagens aceitam sobrecarga e permitirá ter dois métodos com mesmo nome e assinaturas não polimórficas.

Construtores não são polimórficos, na verdade são estáticos. Assim funciona:

```
class Pessoa {     
    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $sexo;  
    public function __construct($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo) {
        $this->nome  = $stringNome;
        $this->idade = $stringIdade;
        $this->sexo  = $stringSexo; 
    }  
} 

class Funcionario extends Pessoa { 
    private $empresa;
    private $salario;
    public function __construct($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo, $stringEmpresa, $stringSalario) {
        parent::__construct($stringNome, $stringIdade, $stringSexo);
        $this->empresa = $stringEmpresa;
        $this->salario = $stringSalario;     
    }
}

$vendedor = new Funcionario("Yuri", "19", "Masculino", "Tam", "3000");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vunpix). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xlozxyqe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Polymorphism0.php).

Claro que um dia se essa mesma pessoa deixar de ser uma funcionário e passar ser outra coisa na organização tem que matar esse pessoa se fazer a ressurreição como outra coisa. Acho isso muito estranho.

Se a pessoa puder ser um funcionário e outra coisa ao mesmo tempo, terá dois objetos que no fundo é a mesma pessoa? Se puder ser um cliente e a pessoa for jurídica terá que diferenciar se o cliente é física ou jurídica? Que rolo.

Quando conceitua errado, OOP não salva ninguém.

Quando se faz OOP só porque todo mundo está fazendo, só do jeito que uma pessoa disse que é o certo e a massa fica copiando sem entender porque está fazendo aquilo não é adequado.

Comment: Apenas a título de curiosidade, se for focar somente na questão POO, o AP poderia seguir uma abordagem usando _decorator_, uma vez que ele permite adicionar ou alterar o comportamento ao objeto individualmente sem afetar os demais objetos. Entretanto, tal abordagem depende, também, do todo (o que nós não temos aqui) e, além do mais, o _decorator_ deve ser usado para casos específicos (conforme sua motivação) o que pode não ser o caso do AP.

Answer (score 0):

A forma como modelamos nossas classes vai depender do comportamento (regras) definidas para a aplicação. No modelo abaixo considerei que na sua aplicação, uma pessoa não pode ser simplesmente uma **Pessoa** (instância direta da classe), por este motivo o construtor da classe **Pessoa** foi definido como protected, ou seja, deverá ser chamado por outra classe que herde de Pessoa.

Se considerarmos que **Nome**, **Idade** e **Sexo** são atributos primários da classe, podemos utilizar um construtor e receber esses dados já na hora em que criamos uma instância do objeto. Já para recuperar os valores gosto de utilizar a abordagem *getAtributo*, assim sei que esse método publico é utilizado para recuperar um atributo. O tratamento/formatação visual pode ficar por conta de uma classe auxiliar ou pode ser feito diretamente no arquivo que chama o método.

Veja o código:

```
<?php

class Pessoa{     

    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $sexo;  

    protected function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
    }

    protected function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    protected function getIdade()
    {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    protected function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }
} 

class Funcionario extends Pessoa
{ 
    private $empresa;
    private $salario;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo, $empresa, $salario)
    {
        parent::__construct($nome, $idade, $sexo);
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
        $this->salario = $salario;
    }

    public function getEmpresa()
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    public function getSalario()
    {
        return $this->salario;
    }
}

$funcionario = new Funcionario("Yuri", "19", "Masculino", "Tam", "3000");

echo $funcionario->getNome() . ' Trabalha na: ' . $funcionario->getEmpresa() . ' e ganha ' . $funcionario->getSalario();
```

Vamos a uma segunda abordagem. Pessoalmente gosto de utilizar os famosos *setAtributo* para definir o valor das minhas variáveis, mas por qual motivo faço isso? Simples, para incluir validação na atribuição de valores. O exemplo abaixo é bem simples e não reflete um fluxo real de validação de dados, mas serve para passar uma ideia de como a coisa funciona:

```
<?php

class Pessoa{     

    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $sexo;  

    protected function setNome($nome)
    {
        if(is_string($nome)) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function setIdade($idade)
    {
        if(is_int($idade)) {
            $this->idade = $idade;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function setSexo($sexo)
    {
        if($sexo == 'M' || $sexo = "F") {
            $this->sexo = $sexo;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getIdade()
    {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    public function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }
} 

class Funcionario extends Pessoa
{ 
    private $empresa;
    private $salario;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo, $empresa, $salario)
    {
        self::setNome($nome);
        self::setIdade($idade);
        self::setSexo($sexo);
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
        $this->salario = $salario;
    }

    public function getEmpresa()
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    public function getSalario()
    {
        return $this->salario;
    }
}

$funcionario = new Funcionario("Yuri", "19", "Masculino", "Tam", "3000");

echo $funcionario->getNome() . ' Trabalha na: ' . $funcionario->getEmpresa() . ' e ganha ' . $funcionario->getSalario();
```

Obs: observe que utilizei `self::setNome` na classe **Funcionario**, porém, também iria funcionar como `$this->setNome` já que estamos falando de uma herança, entretanto, prefiro utilizar **self** pois isso deixa claro que o método foi herdado e atribui semântica ao código.

Você pode ainda definir o `strick_types=1` e então trabalhar com 'tipagem manual' de entrada e saída (retorno). Veja um exemplo simples:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class Pessoa{     

    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $sexo;  

    protected function setNome(string $nome) : bool
    {
        if(!is_null($nome)) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function setIdade(int $idade) : bool
    {
        if(!is_null($idade)) {
            $this->idade = $idade;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Entendi, mas, nesse seu segundo exemplo self::setNome($nome), eu poderia usar parent::setNome($nome) ? eu testei aqui, não alterou nada, existe alguma diferença de chamar o método set ou get herdado da classe "->", ou de chamar diretamente no método do pai ?

Comment: @YuriGabriel sua pergunta é muito boa. Para não correr o risco de passar uma informação incompleta ou incorreta, peguei está dúvida e gerei uma nova pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247723/dúvida-quanto-ao-uso-de-this-self-e-parent, gerei essa nova pergunta pois de certa forma são assuntos diferentes.