# Quando uso o método __construct não preciso usar o get; set?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho o método `__construct` na classe, devo criar os métodos set e get?

```
    <?php 
class Produto{
    //atributos
    private $descricao;
    private $preco;

    //método construtor
    public function __construct($descricao, $preco){
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        $this->preco = $preco;
    }

    //métodos

    public function getDetalhes(){
        return "O produto {$this->getDescricao()} custa {$this->preco} reais";
    }

    /*
    public function setDescricao($valor){
        $this->descricao = $valor;
    }

    public function setPreco($valor){
        $this->preco = $valor;
    }
    */
    public function getDescricao(){
        return $this->descricao;
    }

    public function getPreco(){
        return $this->preco;
    }


}

$p1 = new Produto('livro', 50);
//$p1->setDescricao('livro');
//$p1->setPreco(50);


//var_dump($p1);
echo $p1->getDetalhes();


?>
```

Até cheguei a esta outra [dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45285/quando-usar-m%C3%A9todo-m%C3%A1gico-contructor-ou-set-e-get) mas não ficou claro para mim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não temos como saber. E essa é a única resposta correta para essa pergunta específica.

Uma coisa que as pessoas não entendem sobre orientação a objetos é que não é uma maneira de aplicar receitas de bolo e tudo ficar lindo e funcionará maravilhosamente. [Não são os mecanismos de OOP que fazem o código ficar bom, como aplicá-los é que faz o código ser bom ou ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276787/101).

Não tem como dizer se algo é o mais adequado ou não sem conhecer o contexto, sem estar se referenciando a um caso concreto. Por isso que sempre falo que esse negócio de "melhores práticas" não funciona. Se fosse uma lista de checagem sempre considerando opções seria uma boa, mas na forma como costumam ser expostas e propagadas elas costumam causar mais mal do que bem. Elas não consideram contexto e, em geral, "empurram" uma ideia que se quer "vender". E não se engane, estão sempre querendo vender algo, eu estou fazendo isto agora. Só você pode discernir o que é melhor e saber quando aplicar o que em cada caso.

A pergunta não tem requisitos, não diz o que precisa fazer, então tanto faz o que vai fazer. É o que eu falo, antes de saber a resposta é preciso saber a pergunta. Quando a pergunta é errada (parte de premissa errada), incompleta (não tem todos os dados necessários), ou é irrelevante (aquilo não importa), a resposta nunca será adequada.

Em exemplos abstratos pode-se falar do mecanismo, mas não pode-se falar da adequação dele. E a pergunta é sobre a adequação e não sobre o mecanismo.

Eu não sei se precisa do construtor, não sei se ele é suficiente. Não sei se deve ter como acessar ou permitir modificar cada um dos membros isoladamente. E se puder, não sei se não deveria ter algo mais nele. Não sei se um campo público é suficiente, em geral no PHP é. Não sei se o correto deveria usar o `__get()` e `__set()` padrão da linguagem. Não sei se deveria ser uma classe ou um *array* associativo, quem sabe com algumas funções soltas, é suficiente.

Se o código fosse esse, eu iria pelo caminho mais simples que é um *array* associativo com uma função que entregue os dados mais formatados. Se tivesse um contexto aí eu poderia dizer como eu faria. Mas já adianto que em PHP eu ainda faria de forma muito simples, não criaria coisas desnecessárias. Não adoto o [*cargo cult programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que entendi o que quis dizer, complexo então.. Basicamente devo aprender OOP porém nem tudo que diz é o que é?

Comment: É complexo mesmo.

Comment: Na minha opinião o __construct e alguns outros métodos nativos OOP só servem par complicar, já que vc pode optar por métodos mais simples e práticos.

Comment: E pode optar por não fazer OOP que também complica. Mas se for fazer OOP, eles são bem úteis.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser acessar os atributos $descricao e $preco, sim. Se eles fossem públicos, você poderia ler e modificar eles direitamente usando

```
$p1->preco = 10;
```

mas como na sua classe os atributos são privados, você tem que usar os métodos get e set para poder ler e modificar eles, como você fez nos comentários.

É bom usar métodos get e set para controlar a visibilidade dos seus atributos e os valores que eles podem ter. Por exemplo, pode fazer testes como esse antes de atribuir o valor no atributo:

```
public function setPreco($valor){
    // Não podemos ter um preço negativo
    if($valor >= 0)
        $this->preco = $valor;
}
```