# Quais as limitações do paradigma orientado a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, projeto-de-software, paradigma-de-programação

Minha experiência é mais com o paradigma orientado a objetos. Ok, "se tudo o que você tem é um martelo, todos os problemas se parecem com pregos".

E digo: é um paradigma complicado, cheio de boas práticas, S.O.L.I.D., princípios de design, padrões de projeto, *code smells* e um modelo mental que, se por um lado reduz o hiato representacional entre o problema e a solução, por outro exige tempo, estudo e experiência para aprender a modelar essa solução de acordo com o que o paradigma pede e de forma a obter os benefícios que ele propõe. De "objetos são uma forma natural de pensar" ele não tem nada. Não no médio longo prazo pelo menos, quando os problemas de *design* começam a aparecer.

É uma arma poderosa com risco de se dar um tiro no pé. Usa-se talvez por falta de coisa melhor, mas entendo  quando dizem que é *mainstream* demais. Talvez devido a marketing. Mas foi um paradigma muito pesquisado e não acredito que tanta gente se engane em ele ser benéfico para um grande número de usos.

Pode-se dizer que o problema está no desenvolvedor que não investe tempo em dominar o paradigma. Não sei se outros paradigmas padecem do mesmo problema, ou se o problema é a disciplina de design em si que é complicada de forma geral, ou entra em conflito com as *deadlines* dos projetos na hora de se avaliar um *design*, ou as duas coisas.

Porém o paradigma de OO em si recebe algumas críticas. Na [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Criticism) a maior parte vem de proponentes/idealizadores de linguagens funcionais. Não conheço os argumentos, mas isso sugere uma puxada de sardinha para esse paradigma (não estou dizendo que existe uma dicotomia aí, apenas que os argumentos correm o risco de serem enviesados e não existe vantagem em defenderem um paradigma que não tem perspectiva de suplantar outro - está, pelo menos nesse aspecto existe uma dicotomia).

Minha pergunta é: como se não bastassem essas críticas (ou talvez devendo dar mais atenção a elas), há outras das quais o programador OO precisa estar consciente? Quais os pontos fracos de OO?

Comment: Computacionalmente não há limite. Assim como o funcional ou mesmo o baseado em máquinas de Turing. Há limitação na manutenção e legibilidade, entretanto

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sendo as linguagens por baixo todas Turing-complete, de fato não há. Mas você quer dizer que outros paradigmas são mais fáceis de manter e mais legíveis? Pode elaborar?

Comment: Concordo com a maior parte, discordo principalmente de `Mas foi um paradigma muito pesquisado e não acredito que tanta gente se engane em ele ser benéfico para um grande número de usos.`. As pessoas vivem usando coisas de forma enganada (o ser humano adora se enganar, ele faz isso o tempo todo, essencialmente todo mundo). Ele é útil algum número de casos. E ele não foi tão estudado assim, e onde foi muitas vezes mostra que ele não é essa maravilha toda. Se fosse bem estudado as pessoas concordariam na definição dele. Nem isso sabem. Então de qual OO está falando? :)

Comment: @Maniero Estou falando do OO do Java, mas todos têm complexidade na hora de elaborar o design, não? Ou um princípio de design OO não se aplica a outro determinado OO?

Comment: Piovezan, infelizmente não consigo elaborar muito =\ Tenho experiência informal no assunto, coisas muito opinativas ou então eu nem consigo expressar a minha intuição no assunto em palavras

Comment: @Maniero `e onde foi muitas vezes mostra que ele não é essa maravilha toda.` Poderia elaborar essa parte?

Comment: @Maniero pesquisei e vi que [OO falhou no reuso de componentes comerciais em larga escala](http://wiki.c2.com/?OoHasFailed) embora não saiba dizer se essa era proposta original do paradigma. Além  disso parece haver falta de evidência empírica em sua efetividade, alguns dizem que [sim](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/809593/), outros que [não](https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/publication/237537652_Productivity_Analysis_of_Object-Oriented_Software_Developed_in_a_Commercial/amp) e [não](http://wiki.c2.com/?OoEmpiricalEvidence). Com essas observações acho q mata o assunto.

Comment: @Piovezan estou escrevendo uma resposta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu tb só vou dar opinião :P, baseado na minha experiência.

Comment: @Piovezan Essa estória de que OO falha no reúso de componentes comerciais em larga escala me parece advir mais de problemas sociais, administrativos e organizacionais do que de problemas técnicos. Existe dificuldade em reúso principalmente porque muita gente programa de qualquer jeito para apagar incêndio, seja por falta de competência, de tempo, de recurso ou do que for, e possibilidade de reúso acaba ficando em segundo plano. Além disso, em muitas empresas que desenvolvem software, departamentos e equipes muitas vezes se transformam em feudos que compartilham pouco código com os demais.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Essa é uma ideia de que você não ia mais precisar escrever código, que bastaria comprar componentes prontos feitos por terceiros. Tinha até a época do J2EE, se não me engano tenho uma revista velha de Java que cita isso. De bater o olho na ideia vejo que não ia vingar, sempre existe algo que precisa ser customizado, não dá pra aplicar o caso geral em tudo. No máximo dá certo o reúso de bibliotecas.

Comment: @Piovezan Esse mercado de componentes para reúso era uma ideia marketeira propagada pelos proponentes do EJB2 e que nunca chegou nem perto de se materializar. Ela é demasiadamente otimista e simplória por esquecer o fator óbvio de que software é complexo e sofre alterações e que regras de negócio são altamente específicas e nada genéricas, e isso é independente do paradigma. Algo que está lentamente suprindo essa ideia é o uso de webservices/APIs seja via SOAP, REST ou o que for. Entretanto, partir de algo assim para dizer que OO falhou por não prover esse reúso é um exagero tremendo.

Answer (score 15):

<sup>Dá pra produzir informação útil aqui, mas nosso mecanismo não ajuda as pessoas entenderem que essa informação não é canônica e universal, que reflete algum viés</sup>

Antes vamos combinar sobre quem usa orientação a objetos. Não vamos falar daquele pseudo programador que não entende nada do que é OO, talvez nem de programação em geral e alguns até matemática básica e não conseguem sequer calcular porcentagem, muito menos sabem interpretar um texto ou problema, não conseguem juntar as partes do que está fazendo, buscar informações de forma estruturada, analisá-las e concluir algo por conta própria. Até porque estas pessoas provavelmente sequer lerão esta página, ou não saberão o que fazer com ela.

Infelizmente eu acho que pelo 90% das pessoas que programam caem nessa categoria, até porque ela é ampla e pega desde o sujeito que deveria ser proibido de vender cachorro-quente na esquina, até aquele que consegue entregar projetos que funcionam e em certa medida estão certos, mas ainda entendem apenas vagamente o que estão fazendo.

Não acho que tem muitas pessoas que entendem o que é OOP, provavelmente nem mesmo quem criou o termo (explico abaixo). E obviamente não estou dizendo que eu é que entendo. As pessoas que afirmam categoricamente que a definição dela é a certa devem sofrer do [efeito Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), que é diferente de ser assertivo quanto ao que ela acredita ser o correto.

Me desculpe se alguém se sente ofendido, minha intenção foi só colocar uma base do que ocorre no mercado para justificar porque chegamos nesse ponto, não quero ofender qualquer pessoa, e se sentiu assim, reflita se pode mudar algo porque se viu que serve para você, ou sofre da [síndrome do impostor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) ou deveria aproveitar para evoluir e mudar de categoria. Acho que as pessoas participando ativamente aqui e quase todos que participam passivamente estão entre os não ofendidos, ou inconscientemente acham ser "impostores".

Não estou falando de ninguém específico!

Infelizmente hoje em dia temos que fazer todo esse *disclaimer*.

Vou dizer o que concordo e discordo da excelente resposta do Victor e na pergunta e adotar um ponto de vista diferente, até porque a pergunta é dúbia sobre quais tipos de problemas ela está falando.

> foi um paradigma muito pesquisado e não acredito que tanta gente se engane em ele ser benéfico para um grande número de usos

Não foi muito pesquisado, seriamente, e o que mais acontece no mundo é as pessoas se enganarem, elas fazem isto o tempo todo, adoram se enganar, todo mundo, alguns mais que outros, em um ponto ou outro. Por que você acha que políticos são tão ruins, mas continuam detendo o poder? Por que o grosso do que consumimos tem alguma coisa ruim e ainda assim nada muda? Por que as pessoas ricas gastam fortunas em coisas que tem pouco ou nada agregado a não ser o fato de ser caro? E vou parar por aqui para não pegar pesado :)

> exige tempo, estudo e experiência para aprender a modelar

Sim, para modelar, para aprender os mecanismos nem é tão complicado assim. Mas é claro que o sujeito que não quer aprender tudo direitinho não vai conseguir nada. Mas aí o problema é outro, ele também não sabe que [não pode usar `double` para dinheiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), [não pode aceitar *inputs* sem validar positivamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101), um [CPF é uma descrição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101), não consegue *debugar* ou fazer uma pergunta na internet, enfim, o problema é mais embaixo.

> objetos são uma forma natural de pensar

Sim, pra quem pensa :P Ok, falando sério agora [é difícil estabelecer limites do objeto](http://wiki.c2.com/?OopAndHumanThoughtProcess) e isso nada tem a ver com o que o Victor respondeu, pensar OOP é a parte difícil.

> Estou falando do OO do Java, mas todos têm complexidade na hora de elaborar o design, não? Ou um princípio de design OO não se aplica a outro determinado OO?

Java não tem uma OO, tem mecanismos de OO, mas o projeto pode ser feito seguindo algumas escolas. Java tem tipagem estática que obriga certos mecanismos funcionar de uma forma. O Victor cobre bem a maioria dos aspectos. Java usa uma série de mecanismos que nada tem a ver com OOP, e as pessoas nem percebem.

## Opacidade de abstrações polimórficas

Corroboro a [visão do jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276787/quais-as-limita%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-paradigma-orientado-a-objetos?noredirect=1#comment565833_276869) que parece estar havendo escrutínio da implementação da linguagem e não do paradigma da orientação a objetos. Mais especificamente, pelo menos em parte, está falando da dificuldade com a tipagem.

Lembrando que em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica as funções são naturalmente polimórficas (ainda que nem todas sejam escritas assim, em linguagem de tipagem estática também não).

Pra mim toda essa seção está falando da dificuldade imposta à tipagem estática quando usa o polimorfismo (não necessariamente OOP).

A dificuldade em usar se dá um pouco se não estiver usando um IDE. Mas não acho que o problema do OOP esteja aí, OOP justamente ajuda o IDE informar melhor a estrutura do código.

O que eu sempre falo é que as pessoas não entendem o que é OOP. Ela não tem essa dificuldade porque é comum ela nem usar isso, principalmente da forma correta. A maioria cria classes e acha que isso é OOP. Mas para o "programador de verdade" concordo que tenha essa dificuldade citada.

Acho que **afeta a legibilidade** do código. Tudo o que precisa de contexto para saber o que vai ocorrer é menos legível. Grifei porque é comum os proponentes de OOP defenderem a legibilidade com unhas e dentes, o que até concordo, só discordo que OOP ajuda nisso. O argumento do Victor mostra que é mais complicado saber o que é aquilo.

Alguns podem dizer que isso afeta mesmo é a inteligibilidade. Que seja. E em consequência a manutibilidade.

As pessoas que defendem OOP costumam vender a ideia que a programação fica mais fácil e isto não é verdade. Dá a impressão que você abstrai e encapsula tudo e fica tudo simples. Esconder a concretude tem suas desvantagens. Adoro abstrações, mas quando usada em excesso só coloca mais carga cognitiva e esconde pontos relevantes. Sei que algumas pessoas vão defender isso com filosofia. Adoro filosofia, mas na hora de fazer o projeto precisa ser com arroz e feijão (sei que vão entender isso errado, mas *whatever*).

[As pessoas complicam demais o que pode e deve ser simples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s87Y-6EgwFI).

## Simulando polimorfismo em uma linguagem estruturada

Com *branches* (`if`, `switch`, etc.) você faz polimorfismo, não apenas simula. Não da maneira como as pessoas costumam se referenciar ao polimorfismo, é verdade. O problema é o mesmo.

Não tem nada de errado em fazer isso, a não ser que tenha um motivo para não fazer. A manutenção pode complicar se precisar adicionar comportamentos, esta forma deixa sem coesão. Mas não é qualquer projeto ou qualquer problema específico que precisa dessa coesão toda. Coesão tem malefícios também. Não estou defendendo o uso deste mecanismo, apenas deixando claro que ele tem utilidade e não usá-lo onde deveria é tão ruim quanto usá-lo onde não deveria. Vejo muito uso equivocado porque a pessoa só vê o polimorfismo tradicional como o correto.

O uso de ponteiro para função tem até mais a ver com programação funcional.

Esses conceitos são mais concretos, o que sempre é mais fácil de entender.

OOP abstrai o mecanismo e torna mais difícil de entender o que está ocorrendo. Mesmo que a pessoa diga que não, até para ela mesma, é comum a pessoa enxergar aquilo como mágica.

[image: É mágica]

## *Double-dispatch*

Concordo e acho um dos maiores problemas do mecanismo todo. Suficiente para desqualificar o uso onde não deve.

É um exemplo abstrato demais para eu afirmar, mas é muito comum esse problema surgir quando se tenta modelar algo que não existe de fato, quando se tenta usar OOP onde não cabe, talvez um relacionamento seria mais adequado.

> Muitas vezes isso passa despercebido

Minha percepção é que isto ocorre demais no uso de OOP.

Aí vem o problema que eu falo, a pessoa fica tão cega em usar OOP para tudo que ela consegue ignorar que tem meios mais fácil de resolver o problema. O modelo relacional costuma ser mais fácil para as pessoas entenderem. Sei lá porque, precisa ter um Pedagogia.SE pra gente perguntar.

Se não me engano [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) resolve isto, mas paga um preço.

## Herança múltipla de implementação

Vejo isso como problema de implementação, que é mais simples em linguagens dinâmicas.

Já discuti várias vezes isso com várias pessoas, muito da reclamação sobre OOP na verdade é sobre a tipagem estática.

Tem várias maneiras de ter herança múltipla. Algumas linguagens fazem isto de forma genérica demais (C++ cof cof), outras podem restringir muito, e é raro, se existir, linguagens que tenham tudo que precisa para funcionar (classes abstratas, interfaces, *traits*, *mixins*, papeis, protocolos, delegações, extensões, atributos ([não estou falando de campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)), etc.).

De fato as pessoas não entendem bem o que herdar, quando juntar coisas, o que é um mecanismo e o que é regra de negócio, qual o limite do negócio daquele objeto, como ele pode ou não pode ser estendido, porque não estender o que poderia por causa de otimização, só para citar algumas coisas. As pessoas não entendem de ontologia e taxonomia. Não que isso seja irrelevante em outros paradigmas, mas em OO é bastante importante.

O projeto começa bem, com o tempo começa ser um monte de gambiarra, porque a pessoa não classificou e nomeou as coisas direito. Ah, mas tem o milagroso *refactoring*. Hum, me parece que essas pessoas só trabalharam em projetos pequenos e de curta duração ou que são muito estaticamente definidos. Conheço quem fala sobre essas coisas e trabalhou em dezenas de vezes mais projetos que eu em um terço do tempo que eu tenho de profissão. Sei lá se elas entendem o que é manter um projeto grande por longo prazo. Não dá tempo pra cuidar de trocentos projetos quando se tem um tão complicado. E para solucionar isso tem gente complicando os projetos ainda mais, mas se seguir a receita padrão que já fez antes, tudo se resolve e parece que a pessoa trabalha muito, produtividade medida em KLOCs.

Já vi gente tendo que mudar o sistema quase inteiro por causa disto. Isto é OOP?

O problema que vejo é que é difícil definir o que é o quê. Claro que precisa entender o mecanismo também. A questão é que se a pessoa souber bem o que está fazendo ela consegue fazer bom uso de outros paradigmas como o [modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101), que é mais simples e organizado.

OOP não faz as pessoas criarem bons projetos magicamente, OOP é só a ferramenta. Só porque você tem água, geladeira e uma serra não quer dizer que conseguirá fazer isto:

[image: Escultura de gelo]

## Herança simples de implementação

Concordo 100%, em especial a última frase do 1º parágrafo. E isto é um modelo relacional e modular e não OO.

Grande parte dos problemas que lidamos hoje foram criados porque começaram fazer herança onde não deve, e em muitos casos não deve. Infelizmente as pessoas não enxergam isso, elas não entendem quais os problemas que ela terá no futuro por ter esse acoplamento.

E adivinha porque muitas vezes não dá problema? Porque o problema era simples e/ou estático demais, e OOP não era necessário aí.

## *Crosscutting-concerns*

É uma limitação de OOP e outros paradigmas. O funcional lida melhor com isso com suas próprias limitações, metaprogramação em suas várias formas também, assim como o modular mas menos porque ele acaba sendo um meio termo, mas ele tem um problema, ele é pior definido que OOP.

> a programação orientada a aspectos não foi bem aceita porque ela tem um forte lado negativo também: faz com que o código adquira nele comportamentos que lá não estão expressos e que estão codificadas muito longe do ponto onde são executadas, sem que haja nenhuma indicação clara para tal fato

OOP também e foi muito bem aceita.

Mas é fato que ela não lida bem com a modelagem do mundo real. Por isso atualmente algumas pessoas negam que isto era o objetivo do paradigma, mesmo estando cheio de material do passado dizendo isso. Então qual é a vantagem de usar OO? Reuso? Tem quem negue também. E só dá para reusar bem se não tentar fazer objetos que cuidam de tudo.

Essa é a maior limitação do paradigma, a taxonomia precisa ser perfeita para funcionar bem, mas isso é difícil ou impossível.

#Foco em objetos e não em ações

Aí fala que as linguagens que se diziam OO se renderam ao funcional. Não são nem um coisa nem outra, apenas permitem algo nessa linha. Essencialmente essas linguagens [são imperativas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

As pessoas focam nas ações e parece ser difícil entender que isto não é OO. OO é estrutura de dados.

## Inextensibilidade de classes

Tem várias soluções para isto. Na verdade, creio que esta limitação não é de OOP, até onde sei OOP puro exige que as classes devam poder ser estendidas. Mas deve haver controvérsias quanto a isto.

> Entretanto, o mix-in ainda tem uma desvantagem, que é a de ser um comportamento atribuído a um objeto que não aparece no código da classe correspondente a esse objeto, estando localizado fora da classe onde é aplicado (e possivelmente em algum lugar bem longe dela e bem difícil de ser determinado).

Essa é uma crítica que faço, proponentes de OOP tendem destruir a coesão querendo colocar tudo junto o que é separado. O procedural/modular/funcional tende a permitir essas composições de forma muito mais simples, facilitando muito a manutenção e simplificando a criação. O erro te cobra bem menos quando é tudo mais granular.

Em linguagens dinâmicas isso costuma ser muito mais simples, mesmo em OOP.

Ali foi apresentado uma limitação do Java. Embora a solução existente em outras linguagens também não seja bem orientado a objeto.

## Injeção de dependências

Concordo. E esta complicação é algo que a maioria não entende direito, e não sabem quando parar de fazer isto. É muito comum violarem o KISS e o YAGNI para ser "OOP".

Ali tem algumas perguntas que são muito difíceis de serem respondidas. Na verdade quase tudo, quando está modelando objetos é difícil. O pior é que as pessoas aprendem que as respostas para isto são receitas erradas. Ensinam em exemplos abstratos ruins e as pessoas não conseguem aplicar no contexto real de forma adequada.

Muitas vezes dizem fazer DI para facilitar o teste. Aí você vai ver os testes e são um amontoado de engenharia ruim, testando o óbvio e deixando de lado o que importa porque a pessoa não entende as dificuldades que ela terá com aquele objeto. Por isso o TDD não funciona. E o teste de unidade feito depois só resolve regressões... se o projeto se mantiver firme na sua filosofia inicial de qualidade, o que é raro em projetos longos que não são produtos para outros desenvolvedores usarem (mesmo estes nem sempre é assim).

## Maior complexidade que outros paradigmas

Concordo com tudo antes dos *bullets*. Pena que as pessoas não entendem que OOP é modelar.

Poucas pessoas chegam no nível de usar OOP bem, e muitas acham que chegaram (não estou falando dos aloprados). Eu não cheguei depois de 30 anos fazendo isto porque eu não faço o mesmo projeto todas as vezes. De novo, aprende fazer melhor quem errou em vários projetos. Quem fez vários projetos, devido ao seu tamanho, provavelmente trabalhou em coisas que OOP não era tão útil assim. Tem exceções.

Fazer um formulário usando as classes da sua GUI não é programar orientado a objeto, é usar o que foi programado orientado a objeto. O mesmo pra MVC e outros *frameworks*. E sim, a maior utilidade de OOP é para construir *frameworks*. Minha experiência em sistemas de negócios é que quase sempre ele tem menos utilidade do que as pessoas imaginam.

Já procuram [estudos que indiquem que OOP tem essas qualidades que propalam e não acharam](https://www.csm.ornl.gov/%7Ev8q/Homepage/Papers%20Old/spetep-%20printable.pdf). Isto não prova nada, a não ser que não tem provas que OOP é tão melhor assim. É tudo percepção. A minha é essa que acabei de dizer acima.

Feito errado, e isso inclui usar OOP onde não deve, não entrega valor.

- Tem quem complica o código só para não quebrar a regra que diz que `switch` é coisa do capeta.
- Vou esperar pra ver se o Victor me diz o que tem de errado em `PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa`. Acho normal, quase toda herança deveria ser em cima de classe abstrata, interface ou algo assim, aí serve só como taxonomia e/ou reuso. Eu acho estranho o `Cliente extends PessoaJuridica` que detona a coesão.
- De fato OOP "puro" não gosta de primitivos. Por isso acho OOP ruim, é coisa de acadêmico e não de engenheiro que usa o que é mais adequado para o problema.
- Em OOP o que mais vejo é o uso do *copycat*.

O fato é que OOP é ensinado tudo errado, e já ficou quase impossível ensinar certo, até porque "ninguém" concorda com o que é OOP. Aí diminui ainda mais a utilidade dela dificultando até a comunicação. E o maior erro é ensinar que OOP resolve tudo muito bem e ignorar outros paradigmas.

## Complexidade extra na representação de conceitos abstratos

Aí parece ser mais um crítica à abstração. É um problema quando diz que só pode fazer de forma abstrata. Modelar coisas que mudam é complicado. Não complicar o que pode ser facilmente mudado é mais complicado de enxergar, aí a pessoa vai no *default* e complica tudo.

Note que todos os produtos usados por nós *devs* usa OOP até certo ponto e vai no concreto onde é melhor.

Claro que todo mundo pode ter a opinião que isto não seja uma crítica válida, eu a valido, até o dia que me provarem que não é válida.

## Programação orientada a objetos tem desempenho inferior

[O problema não é o mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50273/101), é o modelo. Se exagerar começa ter problemas sim. Se precisa do máximo de performance é outra coisa. O funcional tem problemas também. Quando a performance importa, outros paradigmas podem ser mais úteis. [Metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101) pode ajudar na abstração sem custo. É comum OOP acabar escondendo complexidades que só se mostram lentas tarde demais. Claro, é erro de projeto, mas OOP ajuda ter isso.

> The problem with object-oriented languages is they’ve got all this implicit environment that they carry around with them. You wanted a banana but what you got was a gorilla holding the banana and the entire jungle.
>
> -- Joe Armstrong

## Excesso de especificação sem tipos genéricos

Curioso que uma boa modelagem OOP é fazer uso de [genericidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) e não OOP. É um problema de OOP em tipagem estática. E OOP (nem todas definições) prega a herança e não a genericidade.

## Falta de uma definição canônica do que é orientado a objetos

Se cada um entende de um jeito é um paradigma complicado de seguir. É complicado as pessoas se entenderem nos projetos, primeiro tem que aprender qual é o OOP do time, e hoje o time pode ser o mundo.

Se as pessoas sequer sabem o que é OOP fica difícil usar e evoluir no paradigma. Cada hora você é influenciado por uma coisa diferente, não sabe se aquilo que está sendo ensinado se aplica ao subproduto que você está usando. Isto é um dos maiores problemas do paradigma. Boa parte dos erros cometidos nele é por causa disto.

Os [pilares descritos é o que eu acho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101), mas o criador do termo acha que não, se bem que ele mesmo já disse (ou quase isso :) ) que [deveria ter chamado aquilo de orientação à mensagens](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/%7Eram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en) ou [orientado a servidor](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Alan-Kays-definition-of-Object-Oriented/answer/Alan-Kay-11) e diz que [escolheu o termo equivocadamente](https://www.quora.com/What-did-Alan-Kay-mean-by-I-made-up-the-term-object-oriented-and-I-can-tell-you-I-did-not-have-C++-in-mind/answer/Alan-Kay-11).

Tenho me questionado sobre o que é encapsulamento e abstração, tenho a impressão que sempre entendi errado, e muita gente também, por isso ensinam errado e todo mundo aprende errado. Publico algo o dia que eu estiver mais certo (comecei fazer).

Algumas pessoas dizem quase o oposto dessas coisas, então é um problema. É complicado saber se está fazendo certo se tem quem mande pôr tudo na classe, e quem manda cada classe fazer só uma coisa.

O Victor contestou em comentários na resposta dele que herança seja algo inerente a OO. Eu vivo fazendo essas coisas, é complicado lidar com algo mal definido.

Se tiver só um dos três pilares, é OOP? Tem quem diga que sim e diz que é encapsulamento, e acho que pode ser, se considerar que isto é apenas juntar tudo na classe. O único que é exclusivo de OOP é a herança.

Curiosamente tem linguagem de tipagem dinâmica que tem herança de subtipo, não vou citar nomes, mas começa e termina com P :P :D

## Modelo anêmico

É um modelo modular que facilita muito a manutenção. Há pessoas que não têm problema com amontoar tudo em uma classe, ou não enxergam como um problema, mesmo sendo, ou fazem sistemas relativamente estáticos, como já disse mais acima.

Pouco importa se é anêmico ou não, a responsabilidade única importa. Em outros paradigmas é mais fácil ter isso, alguns são automáticos. Acertar o "tamanho" da classe é muito difícil. E vale tudo o que disse ao longo do texto.

100% OOP incentiva violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), e há um movimento forte em relação a isto ultimamente. As pessoas estão ficando malucas :)

[Coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) não é sobre juntar tudo, é sobre juntar o que precisa ficar junto. Sequer se fala em classes. Ser coeso é importante, ser encapsulado ao extremo não.

Coesão depende de contexto. Como modelar isso em OO? Simples, fazendo modular/funcional ou até procedural. Muita pessoas fazem, mas acham que estão fazendo OO (lembre-se, não estou falando dos *noobs*).

Como sequer se sabe a definição do que é OOP, não se sabe os detalhes do que é coeso pra OOP. O que eu sei é que coesão é fundamental, e isto existe em computação há mais de 50 anos, antes de OOP e antes do termo engenharia de software existir. Estou falando do termo usando na nossa área, em outras é secular, ou milenar, sei lá, pergunta pro [ptlang.SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/).

Espalhar as coisas sem critério e juntar tudo sem critério são igualmente ruins.

## Dificuldade de se escrever um compilador

É, isso não importa.

Só é bom deixar claro que linguagens mais modernas (Rust, Go, Erlang, etc.) não estão adotando OOP explicitamente, não a incentivam, e as mais antigas estão se afastando um pouco do paradigma, ainda que neguem. Isto vale pra Java, C# e principalmente C++. As linguagens que apostaram tudo no paradigma não tiveram sucesso. Alias o [Alan Kay considera Lisp é a melhor linguagem que existe](https://bit.ly/3HPgztl) e ela não é OOP, ela não tem nada do que as pessoas falam sobre OOP :)

## Outros problemas

Tem problemas com concorrência. Não tem espaço para detalhar.

O maior problema é a dificuldade em modelar, não é tanto OOP. É que OOP exige fazer certo. Quando perguntado sobre aprender OOP para o Alan Kay, [ele respondeu com um livro que não ensina programação](https://bit.ly/3HS7T5s). Sempre falo, o problema é que as pessoas não conseguem classificar as coisas, e isso é fundamental em OOP. Então ela agrupa coisas distintas. E lidamos com problemas que não conhecemos, ou estamos repetindo o que já fizemos antes, o que não é uma tarefa muito nobre.

Só não gosto tanto da indicação do livro porque quase nada que programamos funciona como biologia. Passa a ideia errada. Daí vem um monte de exemplo ruim de como modelar OO.

Se as pessoas são ruins em ontologia, algo que obriga elas serem boas nisso é um [convite para o desastre](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Só é fácil entender um código escrito bem OO se foi você que escreveu ou está em um idioma muito bem dominado pelo time.

OO inibe a criatividade, porque tem que seguir certos padrões para tudo dar certo. OO dá mais certo para fazer coisas recorrentes. Nem vou falar de DDD que é OO na pior forma (a ideia do DDD é boa, a implementação adotada é uma das coisas mais terríveis que já vi na computação).

[SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101) é um caso interessante. Ele é ou não é OOP? Se você seguir tudo direitinho estará fazendo programação modular/funcional e nada do que tem nele é exclusivo de OOP, na verdade algumas coisas de OOP não estão no SOLID. A impressão que tenho que ele se opõe a OO. Se isto for verdade, e é claro que acho que é, seria mais um caso que precisa sair da pureza do paradigma para conseguir o que quer. E é preciso saber tudo isto.

> The difference between people who like OOP languages and these people
> are that these people are pioneers who are actually solving huge
> problems in computing; whereas the designers, supporters, and
> implementers of OOP languages waste all their efforts on aesthetics or
> trying to prevent a strawman idiot from doing idiotic things.
>
> -- Joe Armstrong

[O item 4 da última objeção é o mais importante](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/why_oo_sucks).

Se você pesquisar por OOP, OOD ou palavra que indica a mesma coisa junto com *flaw*, *sucks*, *evil*, *bad*, *problem*, *misuse*, e coisas parecidas vai encontrar um monte de coisa, a maioria faz sentido.

## Conclusão

Acho que há muita avaliação de implementações, de linguagens e não do paradigma na resposta do Victor. Aparentemente a resposta indica que não importa ser OOP, importa é uma linguagem que se diz OOP poder fazer tudo mesmo através de outros paradigmas. Posso ter entendido errado. Mas é fato que isto indica que OOP puro não dá certo.

OOP não resolve todos os problemas e adiciona novos. Na sua forma pura exige fazer coisas bem pouco pragmáticas e códigos ineficientes. Exige coisas que a maioria das pessoas não estão qualificadas para fazer e feito errado ele causa mais problemas. Quem criou o termo também acha que [os problemas são complexos demais e precisa de um entendimento que as pessoas não têm, e eles não podem ser resolvidos de forma isolada](https://bit.ly/3loUyKs) como as pessoas querem. Eu entendo que ele sabe que OOP não é tudo isto, o problema são as pessoas que acham que é.

Há dois grupos de pessoas: as que estão se distanciando<sup>*</sup> de OOP (ou já ficaram distantes) mesmo que nem percebam isso, e as que estão se enfiando no buraco do paradigma cada vez mais. A boa notícia é que se tiver este tipo de atitude a maioria dos problemas que cuidamos não causa muita dificuldade hoje em dia, até porque os problemas são pequenos e estáticos demais para causar.

<sup>*</sup>Distanciar não é abandonar, é usar onde precisa.

É o maior problema que temos na nossa área, e vem piorando: algo muito bom é criado e serve para 1% dos problemas, quem sabe 10%, mas as pessoas querem usar para 100% deles.

[Frases de excelentes programadores (quase todos) que fazem ou fizeram coisas importantes, batendo em OOP](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/08/15/what-is-wrong-object-oriented-programming.html), pelo menos na forma como as pessoas usam. Parecem frases vazias, mas se procurar vai achar o contexto onde foram ditas e quase todas tem argumentos concretos por trás da frase.

Leia os comentários da pergunta, o AP achou mais coisas interessantes.

Eu gosto do [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)), não tudo, mas a ideia básica, porque se fizer tudo aquilo foge da ideia central de OO. Pelo menos é apenas uma linha guia e que diz que você deve fazer o que precisa ser feito para atingir uma meta geral. Não quer dizer muita coisa, mas é melhor que ter "regrinha" que precisa seguir puramente porque senão você é um bocó.

Se seguir todas as regras que inventaram e continuam inventando (OO tem regras novas quase todo dia :) ) pode dar certo. Se seguir uma série de regras em outros paradigmas também tem grande chance de dar certo, muitas vezes mais, só que essas regras não foram disseminadas, talvez porque foram criadas antes da computação "explodir".

Como nota curiosa é ver a ironia do Rob Pike, o criador do UTF-8 e esta parte é importante nesta frase, dizendo que OO é o mesmo que números romanos.

> Object-oriented programming is popular in big companies, because it suits the way they write software. At big companies, software tends to be written by large (and frequently changing) teams of mediocre programmers.
>
> -- Paul Graham ([o texto todo é interessante](http://www.paulgraham.com/noop.html))

> It is not OOP that is broken — we just haven’t figured out (after over
> 40 years) how best to develop with it
>
> --Oscar Nierstrasz

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bati nos 30000 caracteres pela primeira vez. A parte de outros problemas vou ter que ver como vou terminar, só iniciei algumas ideias :)

Comment: A parte de "refatorar o sistema inteiro" me lembrou uma resposta do Mestre Programador: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185404/64969

Comment: Outra resposta caprichada :) Fica até difícil saber qual resposta aceitar. Em relação ao limite de 30K caracteres não daria para dar uma segunda resposta? Só lamento conhecer tão pouco de linguagens dinâmicas, parte da discussão se perdeu para mim. Aceito sugestões de linguagens para aprender que ajudem a entender os problemas levantados.

Comment: Quanto ao `PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa` é porque `PessoaJuridica` é um termo que se concretiza no mundo real normalmente como `Empresa`, o que leva a `Empresa extends Pessoa`. No mínimo é uma escolha pobre de nomenclatura, mas quase sempre é algo muito além, uma modelagem muito ruim. Fora do Brasil e de países lusófonos, nunca vi ou ouvi falar alguém fazendo `Company extends Person` e `PhysicalPerson extends Person`. Ou seja, é um termo peculiarmente curioso do juridiquês tupiniquim que acaba contaminando a modelagem do sistema.

Comment: No mais, vou demorar um tempo para digerir sua resposta e pensar em algum tipo de réplica ou no que posso editar na minha resposta face a isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acho um problema de ontologia, prefiro PessoaJuridica porque é isso que essa entidade é. Empresa é um subconjunto de pessoa jurídica que só pode ser definido por uma informação auxiliar, nem sempre disponível ou relevante. Ou seja, pra mim é uma escolha rica, dentro da minha experiência cuidando de ERPs. Não sei tudo como funciona fora do Brasil, e meu inglês é parco para afirmar algo, mas pra mim Company é Empresa e Organization é a nossa Pessoa Jurídica. O fato das pessoas fazerem assim, errado, não é uma boa justificativa para fazer igual.

Comment: O termo não é invenção nossa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person, mas isso é tópico pro ptlang.SE.

Comment: @Maniero O problema não é ter uma entidade `PessoaJuridica`, é fazer com que `PessoaJuridica` e `PessoaFisica` tenham uma superclasse em comum por serem coisas supostamente parecidas. Em geral são coisas tão diferentes que ou as subclasses herdam um monte de coisas que não deveriam ou então você tem uma superclasse tão vazia que serve para pouca coisa e nesse caso o melhor seria usar uma interface (interface essa que é o tipo que denota para quem você pode enviar uma fatura, por exemplo), isso supondo que você tenha tipagem estática obviamente e nada de *duck typing*.

Comment: De qualquer forma a questão da nomenclatura é o de menos aqui. Normalmente o problema é muito maior ao induzir o programador a usar herança onde não deveria só por causa da nomenclatura.

Comment: A ideia da interface é boa, inclusive se não for uma, tem que ser uma classe abstrata. Não vejo problema nela ser pobre se servir ao propósito. Também não acho que seja fundamental ter isso, mas me parece bem útil na maioria dos casos (sempre estou falando de problemas gerais, tem casos específicos que pode ser melhor fazer de outro jeito). A questão do nome e sua classificação que eu falo é justamente porque definido errado induz a organizar errado e aí usa-se herança onde não deve, separa o que é junto e junta o que é outra coisa. Se organizar certo e nomear errado até está razoável.

Comment: Bom, eu particularmente pra mim mesmo não posso negar ou rejeitar a ideia que existe uma _brasileiridade_ que normalmente se confunde com padrões ortodoxos (ou não) de desenvolvimento. Independente de OO, ou qual quer seja o paradoxismo popular ou acadêmica é fato que o Brasil existe uma peculiaridade de sistema (bem) legados que foram feito praticamente moldados nos processos que as empresas desenvolveram e evoluíram, ou seja não gosto de misturar discussões sobre nomenclatura de classes, funções, tabelas, etc porque senão saio da ciência exata para uma ciência holística ...

Comment: @Maniero Como C++ se classifica? É também uma linguagem com elementos de OO como o Java? Quais seriam linguagens orientadas a objeto além do Smalltalk?

Comment: @Piovezan sim, e há até quem questione se ela é OO. Smaltalk até é, mas não puramente, como paradigma secundário não tem como ser só OO. Tem umas descendentes de Smalltalk, talvez Self e Cecil sejam os melhores exemplos de manter um filosofia parecida. O Alan Kay diz que Lisp é bem OO, mas é porque ela pode sofrer uma metamorfose e pode ser qualquer coisa. C++ vem de Simula que tende dar mais valor para a tipagem estática e o baixo custo de abstração, Smalltalk prega a flexibilidade, custe o que custar. É mais fácil fazer OO em Smalltalk, mas é duro programar certo nela.

Comment: @VictorStafusa presente pra vc: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279342/101 além de acharem que OOP cura câncer, acham que *generics* cura AIDS. Eu estava respondendo ele apagou.

Comment: Me parece ser apenas mais uma pergunta mal-elaborada por alguém que não sabe direito o que é que está fazendo.

Comment: @Maniero _"isso nada tem a ver com o que o Victor respondeu, esta é a parte difícil"_ - o que é a parte difícil? _"O argumento do Victor mostra que é mais complicado saber o que é aquilo"_ "aquilo" seria o código opaco? _"As pessoas que defendem OOP (...)"_ desse parágrafo só consegui tirar que "abstrações devem ser usadas com parcimônia, o resto ficou muito vago. _"talvez um relacionamento seria mais adequado"_ como assim relacionamento? _"O modelo relacional"_ estamos falando de banco de dados?

Comment: @Maniero _"Concordo 100%, especialmente a última frase"_ qual frase? _"E isto é um modelo relacional e modular e não orientado a objeto"_ se refere à modelagem de Carro e Veiculo? _"As pessoas focam nas ações e parece ser difícil entender que isto não é OOP."_ não entendi. _"Ali tem algumas perguntas (...)"_ parágrafo inteiro vago. Apesar que não entendo DI, quem sabe melhore o entendimento quando entender a mágica.

Comment: @Maniero _"Aí você vai ver os testes (...)"_ Não entendi a frase, na verdade não entendi a relação entre DI e o design do teste. Mas igualmente, não domino testes unitários. _"Concordo com tudo até os bullets"_ isso inclui ou exclui os bullets? "_Pena que as pessoas não entendem isso_" isso o quê, que modelar é difícil? _"copycat"_ quis dizer copy/paste? _"Complexidade extra na representação de conceitos abstratos"_ seção vaga, só consegui concluir que nem sempre fazer da forma abstrata é melhor.

Comment: @Maniero "_É um problema de OOP em tipagem estática_" comentário: genericidade deveria ser um "puxadinho" de OOP em tipagem estática, recomendando a aplicação nos casos pertinentes :) _"As pessoas que não tem problema"_ seria "Há pessoas"? _"OO dá mais certo para fazer coisas repetitivas"_ que tipo de coisas? _"Na sua forma pura"_ O que seria OO puro, "tudo são objetos"? _"esse tipo de atitude"_ que atitude, usar somente onde precisa? (acabou!)

Comment: @Piovezan Pensar OOP é diferente de pensar naturalmente, isto é difícil. "Aquilo" é é o objeto, o que fará pode ter várias formas, ser objetos diferentes, não deixa de ser um pouco de opacidade. Não tenho espaço para ser menos vago. Os seja, a pergunta é ampla :) Você entendeu o que importa o resto é quase divagação mesmo :D E estamos falando do modelo relacional (mais ou menos), mas não de banco de dados, o modelo não é exclusivo de DB.

Comment: @Maniero Faltou numerar as dúvidas. Por comentário: 1 a 5; 6 a 9; 10 a 14; 15 a 19. Talvez fique mais fácil responder numerando-as.

Comment: Ult frase ficou sem contexto mesmo:"Ocorre que mesmo a herança simples introduz problemas". Isso, à modelagem apresentada, e não sei se concordo com tudo da modelagem, mas depende do caso, é o que eu falei, nem sempre é fácil definir o problema corretamente. As pessoas se preocupam com o algoritmo e não a estrutura de dados que é mais importante, OOP é estrutura de dados, zero algoritmo. Veja todas interrogações na seção de DI do Victor. Cabe um capítulo dse um livro só pra esclarecer melhor isto.

Comment: O pessoal diz que sem DI fica difícil testar. E pregam testes como solução pra tudo, mas fazem testes horríveis só pra dizer que fizeram (mas acham que estão abafando). Exclui os *bullets*. Não entendem que modelar é OOP e isto é difícil, elas acham que classe é OOP. Copycat é imitação, google it.  Falar de abstração é quase um capítulo também. Lembre-se da opacidade. Ela boa até certo ponto, ruim quando passa do ponto. Sua conclusão está certa. Sua dúvida ficou vaga :P

Comment: É virtualmente impossível ter tipagem efetivamente estática sem generics, ñ tem nada a ver c/ OOP. em tipagem dinâmica OOP não precisa de generics porque é um mecanismo pra resolver a tipagem. O "Há" até ficaria melhor ali agora, mas eu me perdi no meio e ia terminar o parágrafo, depois eu reviso ele. OOP "é modelar", e você só modela bem o que já modelou antes, já sabe o que erros, então funciona melhor quando você resolve os mesmos tipos de problemas. OOP puro é quando não adota outros mecanismos pra ajudar o que o paradigma não é bom...

Comment: ... E essa ideia de tudo ter que ser objeto é um dos causadores de problemas, as linguagens nem conseguem fazer tudo ser objeto de fato. Atitude ruim de se enfiar em OOP com tudo como se ela resolvesse tudo. FIM. De fato teria ficado melhor c/ uma numeração, aqui ficará confuso também. É por causa disto que eu achei que a pergunta deveria ser deveria ser fechada. Isso funciona melhor em fórum mesmo, embora hoje eu ache que bem feito seja útil em qualquer lugar.

Comment: @Maniero _“100% OOP incentiva a violar o DRY”_ do que está falando exatamente?

Comment: @Piovezan Se você ficar colocando tudo no objeto como manda o paradigma (pelo menos como alguns dizem) fatalmente você terá repetição de código. Quem propõe OOP acha que não pode ter nada fora da classe, que não pode ter classe estática e essas coisas que sã ousadas para fazer composição. Então viola o DRY de código e viola o DRY de dados, porque muitas vezes o mesmo objeto real passa ter mais de uma representação dentro do sistema quando ela assume papéis diferentes, caso tipo da `Pessoa` que é `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` ao mesmo. Quem costuma fazer OOP tem 2 objetos que são a mesma pessoa.

Answer (score 12):

O paradigma de programação orientada a objetos impõe algumas dificuldades. Elas podem ou não ser superadas em maior ou em menor grau. A lista que se segue não é de forma alguma exaustiva, mas deve servir para responder essa questão.

## Críticas reais que considero válidas

Aqui listo algumas coisas que considero problemas típicos em linguagens de programação orientadas a objetos que podem ser desvantagens.

#### Opacidade de abstrações polimórficas

O paradigma de programação orientada a objetos é significativamente mais complexo que o estrutural/procedimental porque agora as funções e procedimentos são substituídas por métodos possivelmente polimórficos e até mesmo abstratos. Esse polimorfismo não permite mais que a função/procedimento ora invocado possa ser determinado precisamente de antemão, de forma que ele só se tornará conhecido em tempo de execução. Isso daí pode deixar a análise e a compreensão de programas mais complicada.

Num programa procedimental/estruturado, quando uma função `xpto` é invocada, sabe-se exatamente de forma estática onde ela está e você pode então rapidamente olhar o código dela. Ou seja, nesse caso, a abstração é transparente, pois você consegue localizar e inspecionar o seu conteúdo facilmente. Já no orientado a objeto não. As chamadas aos métodos na programação orientada a objetos podem ser abstratos e polimórficos, sendo determinados somente em tempo de execução, e por isso sendo opacos, ou seja, não passíveis de serem rapidamente localizados e inspecionados.

Isso é algo que tende a atrapalhar iniciantes em OO que ficam com aquela coisa de não saber exatamente que método estão chamando, vez que pode haver múltiplas implementações. Pode complicar quando você está olhando para o código, procurando por algum bug ou tentando entender algum comportamento do código e cai em um método abstrato e fica sem saber onde encontrar a implementação dele ou mesmo qual das diversas implementações é a que interessa.

***Simulando polimorfismo em uma linguagem estruturada***

Programas escritos em linguagens de programação procedimentais não costumam tentar utilizar-se explicitamente de polimorfismo. Entretanto, a necessidade de polimorfismo existe quando vemos aquela função `salvar` que tem um parâmetro do tipo `int` onde 1 é um arquivo, 2 é um socket, 3 é um pipe, etc. Ou onde ao invés de ter apenas uma função `salvar`, temos a função `salvarNoArquivo`, `salvarNoSocket`, `salvarNoPipe`, etc.

É possível simular-se o polimorfismo em programação procedimental por meio do uso de ponteiros de função ou por meio de funções que têm um `if` ou `switch` gigantesco dentro para escolher a implementação adequada. Entretanto, nota-se que ao fazer-se isso, se está na verdade fazendo-se uma gambiarra com o objetivo de simular um paradigma diferente do que aquele a linguagem impõe.

No caso de uma linguagem procedimental, o uso de polimorfismo baseado em ponteiros de função, se feito de forma padronizada e bem organizada acaba por produzir um padrão de projeto capaz de simular o polimorfismo das linguagens orientadas a objeto (inclusive, é exatamente assim que elas são implementadas na prática). Mas usam-se construções bem atípicas e com estruturas bem diferentes daquelas que seriam as naturais para a linguagem. Ou seja, a gambiarra vira um padrão de projeto promovendo algo que não é natural de ser expresso na linguagem em questão.

Ao fazer-se isso em uma linguagem procedimental, a opacidade da orientada a objeto surge e não é mais possível saber-se estaticamente qual função será chamada já que o que se tem é um ponteiro de função cujo valor só é conhecido em tempo de execução (ou mesmo que seja/fosse um valor a ser usado um `switch`zão bem grande). A estrutura do programa resultante apresenta uma complexidade extra que serve apenas para simular a orientação a objetos no programa procedimental, complexidade essa que desapareceria se a linguagem fosse orientada a objetos, mas sem que a opacidade das abstrações correspondentes desapareçam. Isso demonstra que essa opacidade não é de fato algo que a programação procedimental está imune, e sim algo que surge quando o polimorfismo lhe é adicionado.

#### *Double-dispatch*

Isso daqui é o oposto do item anterior, é falta de abstração suficiente. Chamadas polimórficas usam o objeto a qual se referem como um contexto no qual elas executam a fim de prover uma dimensão de polimorfismo. Ocorre que nem sempre uma só dimensão é suficiente.

Por exemplo, imagine que tenhamos diversos tipos de robôs que inspecionam diversos tipos de carros e que cada combinação robô-carro ocorra de uma forma diferente:

- No paradigma estruturado, ou teríamos uma função/procedimento para cada combinação robô-carro ou então teríamos uma única e gigantesca função/procedimento com um zilhão de `if`s e `switch`es para separar esses casos todos.
- Na programação orientada a objetos, podemos colocar o método `visita(Carro)` na classe `Robo` e escolher o tipo de carro dentro de cada implementação ou então colocar o método `receberVisita(Robo)` na classe `Carro` e escolher o tipo de robô dentro dele. Nenhuma dessas duas abordagens é a ideal porque seja qual for a escolhida, você escolhe se o polimorfismo é baseado no `Robo` ou no `Carro`, mas não nos dois.
- No paradigma ideal, dada uma combinação de `Carro` e `Robo`, ao invocar o método `visitar`, a implementação polimórfica ideal já seria escolhida.

O nome disso é [*double-dispatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), pois a implementação a ser executada depende do tipo de dois objetos ao invés de apenas um (*single-dispatch*).

Há algumas técnicas para tentar se contornar esse problema em linguagens orientadas a objetos, tal como usar o padrão de projeto *Visitor*, técnicas de introspecção ou reflection ou então usar tabelas contendo nela dezenas de objetos que representam cada uma das possíveis implementações diferentes, sendo essas definidas por uma interfaces. Entretanto, nesse caso você já estará a tentar simular um paradigma diferente utilizando construções que não são naturais da linguagem em questão, da mesma forma que ocorre ao simular-se o polimorfismo na programação estruturada. O resultado novamente é uma boa quantidade de código e de complexidade para gerenciar isso que seriam dispensados se a linguagem em questão já tivesse esse recurso embutido.

Muitas vezes isso passa despercebido, mas ocorre por vezes quando temos aquela decisão se criamos na classe `A` um monte de métodos para lidar com todos os tipos diferentes de `B` ou então se criamos na classe `B` um monte de métodos diferentes para lidar com todos os tipos diferentes de `A`, ou então acabamos criando objetos que relacionam diferentes tipos de `A` com diferentes tipos de `B` a fim de escolher o que fazer com eles. Todas essas coisas seriam denecessárias em uma linguagem que já tivesse o *double-dispatch* naturalmente.

#### Herança múltipla de implementação

Uma coisa que têm sido considerada um grande problema em linguagens de programação orientada a objetos é a herança de múltiplas implementações.

As primeiras linguagens a irem por esse caminho permitiram que houvesse herança múltipla de implementação. Os programas resultantes do uso de herança múltipla tendem a ser confusos e difíceis de se entender. O principal problema que surge é o problema do diamante:

```
 class A:
     void x()
         print('a')

 class B extends A:
     void x()
         print('b')

 class C extends A:
     void x()
         print('c')

 class D extends B, C:
     void y()
         x()
```

Observe que o método `y()` da classe `D` invoca o método `x` que foi herdado. Ocorre que não está claro se vai ser chamado o método herdado de `C` ou o método herdado de `B`. Algumas linguagens tentam resolver impondo uma ordem de precedência de herança, mas ela pode criar problemas:

- Um método de `B` pode acabar chamando um método de `C` no mesmo objeto sendo que `B` não é subclasse de `C` e nem `C` é subclasse de `B`.
- Quando há diversos métodos herdados, definir-se a ordem correta das superclasses pode ser difícil. Há casos onde a ordem correta pode variar em diferentes contextos de uma mesma classe implicando que há casos onde nenhuma ordem é a correta.

Um outro problema é em relação aos *cast*s. Em muitas linguagens orientadas a objetos, os objetos são organizados na memória ao colocar-se os membros da superclasse primeiro seguidos dos membros da subclasse. Dessa forma, ao fazer-se o *cast* de um endereço de memória da subclasse para a superclasse, o endereço resultante seria o mesmo. Em um *cast* da subclasse para a superclasse também, o endereço é o mesmo. Porém, quando existe mais do que uma superclasse, esse truque não funciona mais e é necessário fazer-se correções de endereços nos *cast*s, o que trás um monte de complicações e faz com que um mesmo objeto possa ter mais do que um endereço de memória ou tenha que ter uma organização na memória significativamente mais complexa.

#### Herança simples de implementação

Muitas linguagens orientadas a objeto aboliram a herança múltipla de implementação e só permitiram herança simples, com no máximo uma superclasse. Ocorre que mesmo a herança simples introduz problemas.

Analisar e entender o código de uma superclasse pode ser difícil, pois trata-se de um código incompleto a ser terminado ou sobreescrito pela subclasse. Uma subclasse também é algo incompleto, pois ela está fortemente acoplada à sua superclasse. Ou seja, a herança introduz um tipo de [acoplamento forte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Por tal motivo, as subclasses são especialmente frágeis se as superclasses sofrerem alterações. Em especial, é frequente que [o comportamento da subclasse dependa de detalhes da implementação da superclasse, quebrando mesmo frente a alterações de detalhes internos dessa](https://x-stream.github.io/jira/746/).

A herança pode ser quase sempre substituída por composição. Um objeto na memória é composto por vários campos que correspondem a outros objetos (ou a valores primitivos/built-in). Por exemplo, um objeto da classe `Veiculo` seria representado por uma sequência de dados `placa, proprietário, tipo-de-combustível`. Um objeto do tipo `Carro` (subclasse de `Veiculo`) seria representado por `placa, proprietário, tipo-de-combustível, cor, modelo, marca`. Observe que isso é quase o equivalente a fazer com que a estrutura da subclasse fosse `Veiculo, cor, modelo, marca`. Ou seja, ao usar composição no lugar de herança, chega-se a uma estrutura com os mesmos dados, mas a subclasse é mais flexível quanto ao que ela pode encapsular da superclasse e como.

#### *Crosscutting-concerns*

Uma coisa que tende a atrapalhar bastante em programas orientados a objetos é o seguinte caso: Imagine que você tenha um método que salva o cadastro de um funcionário. Ele idealmente seria algo assim:

```java
void salvar(Funcionario f) {
    Arquivo a = ...;
    a.escrever(f.cpf);
    a.escrever(f.nome);
    a.escrever(f.salario);
}
```

Mas, ocorre que você ainda tem que lidar com conceitos como logging, transações, tratamento de erros, entre outros, e o código acaba virando isso:

```java
void salvar(Funcionario f) {
    Logger.trace("Salvando o funcionário " + f.id);
    Arquivo a = null;
    Transacao tx = Transacao.abrir();
    try {
        Arquivo a = ...;
        a.escrever(f.cpf);
        a.escrever(f.nome);
        a.escrever(f.salario);
        tx.commit();
        Logger.trace("Salvou o funcionário " + f.id);
    } catch (ErroDeIO x) {
        Logger.error("Erro ao salvar o funcionário " + f.id, x);
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        a.close();
    }
}
```

Isso introduz muita complexidade adicional e acidental ao programa. Além disso, todas essas funcionalidades de logging, transações, tratamento de erros (denominadas *crosscutting-concerns*) estão espalhadas e copiadas-e-coladas em um monte de lugares diferentes para tudo que é lado no código. Quando algum detalhe no que concerne ao gerenciamento de transações tem que mudar, ele demandará modificações extensas em diversas partes do código.

Há várias tentativas de se resolver isso em linguagens de programação orientadas a objetos, mas todas elas acabam deixando ao menos alguma linha de código, algum comando ou alguma anotação para trás no código que ainda equivale ao *crosscutting-concern*, sendo que o ideal é que não houvesse nada disso no código, mas que isso ainda assim estivesse lá em tempo de execução.

Foi pensando nisso que surgiu a programação orientada a aspectos, que separa o código dos *crosscutting-concerns* do código onde ele é aplicado. Entretanto, a programação orientada a aspectos não foi bem aceita porque ela tem um forte lado negativo também: faz com que o código adquira nele comportamentos que lá não estão expressos e que estão codificadas muito longe do ponto onde são executadas, sem que haja nenhuma indicação clara para tal fato. É difícil ou até mesmo impossível olhar-se para um código e saber quais são os *crosscutting-concerns* que nele se aplicam e se eles estão sendo corretamente gerenciados.

#### Foco em objetos e não em ações

Esta é uma crítica dos defensores de linguagens funcionais às linguagens orientadas a objetos. Em linguagens funcionais você tem lambdas que é como se fossem métodos anônimos, pedaços de código que você pode passar como parâmetro para métodos.

Isso daí dá para simular em linguagens de programação mais puramente orientadas a objeto sem muita dificuldade, mas tem um custo: produz uma explosão no número de classes e de interfaces e uma complexidade significativa para codificá-las. Isso têm sido mitigado nas linguagens de programação orientadas a objetos mais modernas que incorporam os conceitos de lambdas nativamente, tornando-as híbridas entre orientadas a objetos e funcionais.

#### Inextensibilidade de classes

Todo mundo já passou por um caso onde você quer adicionar um método qualquer em uma classe já existente, mas não tem como fazer isso pois tal classe não pode ser modificada. É dessa limitação que classes como `StringUtils`, `DateUtils` e `XptoUtils` da vida acabam surgindo. Essas classes são gambiarras advindas do fato de que há necessidade em estender-se classes que por alguma razão não podem ser modificadas.

A solução para isso está no conceito de *mix-ins*, que consiste em acrescentar-se métodos a classes já existentes, coisas que linguagens como JavaScript e Ruby permitem facilmente e que não dá para se fazer (ao menos não de forma fácil e sem gambiarras) em linguagens como Java e C#. Entretanto, o mix-in ainda tem uma desvantagem, que é a de ser um comportamento atribuído a um objeto que não aparece no código da classe correspondente a esse objeto, estando localizado fora da classe onde é aplicado (e possivelmente em algum lugar bem longe dela e bem difícil de ser determinado).

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você queira acrescentar um método para inverter uma string. Em JavaScript, que suporta mix-ins, isso é fácil:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    let r = "";
    for (let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
        r = this.charAt(x) + r;
    }
    return r;
}

var teste = "abcd";
document.write(teste.reverse());
```

Observe que o código acima usa `teste.reverse()` ao invés de `reverse(teste)`. Isso é porque o método* `reverse` foi injetado dentro da classe* string.

*<sup>: Em JavaScript não há classes e métodos propriamente ditos, mas a forma como ele implementa funções com captura de escopo e protótipos de objetos servem para simular bem esses conceitos.</sup>

No entanto, se tentarmos fazer o mesmo em Java:

```java
 public class StringUtils {
     public static String reverse(String in) {
         return new StringBuilder(in).reverse().toString();
     }
 }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String teste = "abcd";
        System.out.println(StringUtils.reverse(teste));
    }
}
```

Observe que ao invés de usarmos `teste.reverse()`, temos que usar `reverse(teste)`, revertendo a estrutura do código a uma estrutura típica de programação procedimental. Não podemos usar `teste.reverse()` porque não podemos alterar a classe `String` e nem injetar um método externo nela.

A classe resultante `StringUtils` não representa um conceito de orientação a objetos, pois instâncias dessa classe não fazem sentido e ela só serve para agrupar métodos que queríamos que estivessem em outro lugar.

#### Injeção de dependências

Diversos objetos, para poderem realizar o seu trabalho, devem ser capazes de localizar suas dependências, ou seja, outros objetos com os quais devem colaborar.

Fazer com que os devidos objetos se conheçam pode ser algo bastante trabalhoso, pois pode implicar em processos de criação de objetos bastante complicados ou em construtores bem difíceis de se utilizar. Disso advém um monte de padrões de projeto criacionais, como o *Builder* e o *Factory*, que embora sejam padrões de projetos, podem ser vistos também de uma forma negativa como gambiarras inventadas para se contornar limitações da linguagem.

Uma possível solução para isso é a injeção de dependências, onde o objeto *A* declara que ele precisa de uma instância de *B* para operar e quando *A* for criado, *B* é entregue a ele a partir de alguma forma um tanto *mágica* (que muitas vezes acaba se transformando em um *framework* de injeções de dependência ou em um *Service Locator*).

Além disso, há o problema do ovo e da galinha. O objeto "ovo" deve criar o objeto "galinha" ou o objeto "galinha" deve criar o objeto "ovo"? O *DAO* cria o *Connection* ou o *Connection* cria o *DAO*? Esse problema fica mais simples de ser resolvido com injeção de dependências, onde o *framework* responsável por isso se encarrega em descobrir a melhor ordem para criar tais objetos. Se a injeção de dependências puder ser preguiçosa (ou seja, feita sob demanda apenas no momento que é necessária), mesmo se os objetos *A* e *B* dependerem mutuamente um do outro, eles poderão ser criados separadamente e só vão se conhecer quando um precisar do outro.

Nota-se que todas essas abordagens de injeção de dependência novamente acrescentam bastante complexidade a um projeto que vier a usufruir dela. Novamente, caímos no caso onde muita complexidade é adicionada para contornar-se limitações da linguagem de programação ou do paradigma desta.

#### Maior complexidade que outros paradigmas

Entender e saber usar de forma adequada o paradigma de programação orientada a objetos é de fato bem mais difícil do que fazer isso com o paradigma procedimental. Uma coisa é entender o conceito do que é um método, construtor, classe, instância, herança, polimorfismo, etc. Outra coisa bem diferente é saber usar isso de forma efetiva e inteligente.

O projeto de um programa orientado a objetos bem feito é difícil de se fazer, e por vezes acaba sendo mais fácil e mais rápido optar-se por um programa com uma estrutura mais simplista. Por vezes essa estrutura mais simplista é um modelo procedimental com pouca orientação a objetos tal como um [modelo anêmico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) (explico mais sobre ele abaixo).

É muito comum no dia-a-dia se ter prazos apertados e treinamento e experiência insuficientes, o que ocasiona em projetos estruturalmente mais deficientes. Aliás, esse fato ocorre em qualquer linguagem de programação com qualquer paradigma e com qualquer metodologia de desenvolvimento de software, mas afeta mais aqueles que são mais difíceis de se aprender corretamente, tal como o paradigma orientado a objetos.

Quando essa barreira é superada e o programador passa a usar orientação a objetos adequadamente, deixando de programar de forma estruturada ou apenas amontoando um monte de métodos em classes quaisquer, ele ganha bastante flexibilidade e robustez na estrutura do código, principalmente devido ao polimorfismo e ao encapsulamento. Entretanto, para atingir-se esse ponto de maturidade, é necessário percorrer-se um longo e difícil caminho, e muitos simplesmente não querem ou não conseguem chegar lá ou ainda o estão percorrendo e ainda vão demorar algum tempo. Antes de estarem amadurecidos, tentarão usar orientação a objetos (e muitas vezes vão pensar estarem de fato usando) mas não conseguirão colher os frutos dela, tendo então a impressão que é apenas complexidade extra a troco de nada e naturalmente farão diversas críticas, alegando ser improdutiva, excessivamente complexa ou não entregar real valor.

Más práticas de programação em especial tendem a deixar esse caminho já bastante difícil e lento de ser percorrido, ainda mais difícil e lento:

- É comum ver quem insista em usar `switch` ao invés de polimorfismo e ensine isso aos outros.
- É comum ensinar-se modelos procedimentais pintados de OO ao invés de OO de verdade, tais como proliferação de classes que nada mais são do que getters e setters, práticas do tipo `PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa`, classes monstruosas que tem trocentos métodos diferentes para fazer tudo que é coisa a torto e a direito, etc.
- É frequente ver gente usando estruturas de dados inadequadas tais como um monte de ints, strings e arrays ao invés de classes e objetos.
- É comum ver gente imitando padrões e processos de codificação (muitas vezes viciados) sem entender ou questionar o porquê deles.
- É comum ver gente programando na linguagem X imitando os padrões e convenções de codificação da linguagem Y e ignorando os padrões recomendados em X.

Essa disseminação de más práticas torna mais difícil a quem estiver aprendendo a separar o joio do trigo e introduz diversos vícios difíceis de serem desaprendidos depois. Novamente, friso que esse problema de aprendizado e aplicação vale para qualquer paradigma de programação e qualquer linguagem, mas afeta mais fortemente as que são mais difíceis de se aprender corretamente, atingindo em cheio o paradigma de programação orientada a objetos.

## Críticas que não considero válidas

Aqui listo algumas das críticas linkadas na Wikipédia que não vejo como válidas e algumas que já vi em outros locais.

#### Complexidade extra na representação de conceitos abstratos

Uma crítica comum é que muitas vezes pode ser simples e fácil usar um `int` ou uma string para representar alguma coisa do tipo 1=macaco, 2=cachorro, 3=peixe, 4=gato e então colocar um `if` ou `switch` nas partes onde o comportamento varie de um caso para outro ao invés de definir-se classes específicas para todos eles. Em casos mais bobinhos, isso até é válido, mas essa solução não têm escala. Uma coisa é quando há 1 ou 2 lugares onde esses objetos (animais no caso) possam ter comportamentos diferentes e você introduz um código arbitrário 1, 2, 3 e 4 para lidar com isso, outra coisa é quando há 1000 lugares diferentes. A orientação a objetos traz os comportamentos polimórficos para dentro do objeto em questão, eliminando-se a disseminação de `if`s e `switch`es com um monte de códigos malucos e arbitrários que o dominariam de outra forma.

#### Programação orientada a objetos tem desempenho inferior

Embora possa ser verdade que o fato de as chamadas a funções polimórficas demandarem um mecanismo mais complexo que as não-polimórficas para concretizá-las e que isso pode inibir algumas otimizações, na prática esse não é um problema real. Os maiores gargalos de desempenho estão no interior de laços que devem ser executados com muita frequência e da forma mais rápida possível, e os poréns da programação orientada a objetos são otimizados nessas circunstância muito bem por todos os compiladores decentes existentes no mercado, inclusive aqueles de linguagens interpretadas (que tipicamente fazem uma compilação *just-in-time* antes de executar o código).

Além disso, a maioria dos problemas referentes a desempenho se referem a projetos de algoritmos, coisa que muda muito pouco em relação a escolha de procedimental vs orientado a objetos.

#### Excesso de especificação sem tipos genéricos

Frequentemente, apende-se que as classes `BoloDeCenoura`, `BoloDeChocolate` e `BoloDeMorango` são subclasses de `Bolo`, e com isso cria-se um monte de classes e subclasses para todo tipo de coisa. Essa crítica ignora o fato de que essa **não é** uma boa modelagem orientada a objetos, embora muitas vezes seja ensinada assim. O ideal é fazer na classe `Bolo`, um método `getSabor()`. Se o tipo do sabor não deva se perder, que faça-se `Bolo<Cenoura>`, `Bolo<Chocolate>`, `Bolo<Morango>`.

Esse tipo de modelagem de classes aparece quando:

- A linguagem em questão é fortemente tipada mas não tem tipos genéricos e o programador tenta simular isso de uma forma ruim (gambiarra) usando herança.
- O programador modelou assim porque lhe parecia ser uma boa ideia usar a herança para especializar o comportamento dessa forma sem considerar a possibilidade de usar-se composição.

No caso de linguagens com tipagem dinâmica, essa crítica é totalmente inócua. Na verdade, isso é uma crítica ao mal-uso de herança e a falta de tipos genéricos em uma linguagem fortemente tipada. Usar isso para atacar orientação a objetos não é algo válido, embora esse tipo de ataque seja comum.

#### Falta de uma definição canônica do que é orientado a objetos

É verdade que não existe uma definição canônica, única e universal do que é ou não é programação orientada a objetos e definições dela vão variar bastante dependendo de a quem você estiver perguntando. Entretanto, isso é algo que tem pouco valor na prática, e embora possa haver discordância ou divergência quanto a determinados termos e determinadas ocasiões, a maioria das pessoas concorda mais ou menos que programação orientada a objetos prega os conceitos de polimorfismo, encapsulamento, herança (de tipo e de implementação) e à união da estruturas com os códigos que sobre ela operam.

#### Modelo anêmico

Há muitas pessoas que criam objetos do tipo `FuncionarioVO` que contém um monte de campos/atributos e mais um monte de getters e setters com pouca ou nenhuma funcionalidade adicional e então cria classes de negócio do tipo `AtualizaFolhaDePagamentoFuncionario` que contém as regras de negócio que operam sobre `FuncionarioVO`.

Essa é uma arquitetura bastante ruim, denominada de [modelo anêmico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) e que merece muitas críticas por separar os comportamentos que um objeto tem ou pode ter da estrutura do mesmo, espalhando a lógica de negócio em diversos lugares diferentes, promovendo um encapsulamento ruim e uma baixa coesão de classes. Entretanto, esse é uma típica arquitetura de um sistema procedimental, e não orientada a objetos. Numa arquitetura orientada a objetos, os dados de um objeto não devem ser separados dos seus comportamentos, que é exatamente o que o modelo anêmico faz.

Já vi muitas críticas de que o projeto orientado a objetos acaba tornando-se algo complicado e difícil por ser organizado dessa forma. Mas nesse caso o problema não é da orientação a objetos, e sim exatamente por ela ter sido violada. Esse tipo de crítica não é válida por colocar a vítima no banco dos réus.

#### Dificuldade de se escrever um compilador

Já vi críticas à linguagens orientadas a objetos por serem mais difíceis de se escrever um compilador para elas. Ora, nesse caso isso é um problema do compilador e não da linguagem. É verdade que em geral é mais difícil escrever um compilador para uma linguagem orientada a objetos do que escrever um para uma procedimental, mas isso de forma alguma serve como justificativa para não se adotar linguagens orientadas a objeto, no máximo serve como um aviso para alguém que estiver projetando uma linguagem de programação ou estiver a fim de escrever um compilador. Além disso, os desafios inerentes à implementação da orientação a objetos no compilador são em geral bem menores do que outros desafios inerentes a isso, tal como análise sintática e geração de código.

Comment: Em primeiro lugar, obrigado pelo capricho da resposta! Permita-me levantar alguns pontos: sobre a opacidade de abstrações polimórficas e o double-dispatch, confesso que nunca tive problemas com isso, até porque no caso do double-dispatch nunca precisei usar (mas é um ponto válido). Sobre simular polimorfismo, já que você tocou no assunto programação estruturada, devo dizer que suspeito que nesta haja um outro problema importante que seria a escalabilidade limitada, devido à abstração não ser imposta pelo paradigma, mas posso estar falando besteira (cont...)

Comment: Sobre a inextensibilidade de classes, me soa um pouco como se na maioria dos casos o problema fosse o mau design, seja da classe original, seja da versão "Utils". Se tiver um exemplo que não corrobore isso vou querer saber. Quanto ao modelo anêmico, acho interessante notar que ele tem muitos defensores na [SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), a ponto de parecer que a discussão está em "empate técnico" por lá (cont...)

Comment: Por fim, os demais pontos me parecem todos muito corretos. Também tenho curiosidade em saber se você considera a dificuldade de se impor um design correto em OO um problema específico do paradigma ou um caso mais geral que ocorre também no estruturado, por exemplo.

Comment: O modelo anêmico está naquilo que você não considera crítica válida?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É, porque o modelo anêmico é justamente uma violação deliberada dos princípios de OO, fazendo com que a aplicação não obtenha as vantagens do paradigma, por isso não conta como crítica ao mesmo

Comment: @Piovezan Editei a resposta.

Comment: Opa- a resposta está bem completa e extensa - confesso que não li tudo com a devida atenção. mas será que todas as bolas levantadas são _inerentes_ a programação OO, ou algumas são mais por conta de implementações do OO em alggumas linguagens - principalmente estáticas?
Pergunto por que sou programador Python, e a característica de ser dinâmica da linguagem parece que evita quase todos esses problemas (inclusive a linguagem implementa herança múltipla sem nenhum problema)

Comment: @jsbueno No texto, eu afirmo que "*Algumas linguagens tentam resolver impondo uma ordem de precedência de herança*". É exatamente isso que o Python faz ([veja aqui](https://programadorlivre.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/heranca-multipla-em-python/)). Dizer se é inerente a linguagens OO é um pouco difícil, vez que não há definição canônica do que é ou não OO, mas eu arriscaria dizer que herança de implementação (seja simples ou múltipla) é sempre problemática por deixar o programa relaativamente mais confuso e difícil de ser entendido (o que é algo um tanto subjetivo também). [continua...]

Comment: @jsbueno [...continuação] Quanto ao Double-Dispatch só lembro de ter visto uma ou duas linguagens com esse recurso há uns anos (nem lembro mais o nome), nenhuma delas fez muito sucesso, mas é algo sanável em OO e portanto não é inerente a elas, mas que também não é *mainstream*. Já a opacidade do polimorfismo é algo inerente ao próprio polimorfismo e portanto à própria OO: não há como sse ter polimorfismo sem se pagar esse preço. Tanto é que qualquer tentativa de simulaar polimorfismo em uma linguagem que não o tenha fará com que isso acabe surgindo. [continua]

Comment: @jsbueno [...continuação] *Crosscutting-concerns* é algo que pode ser corrigido exatamente com a programação orientada a aspectos (que não exclui a orientada a objetos), mas não sei se o lado negativo é algo inerente a ela (suspeito que não, mas desconheço alternativa). A inextensibilidaade não é algo inerente a OO e linguagens com tipagem dinâmica não sofrem disso. A inextensibilidade também não é inerente da tipagem estática, mas não conheço linguagens com tipagem estática que não sofram desse problema, embora acredito que devam existir. [continua]

Comment: @jsbueno [...continuação] A complexidade adicional é algo inerente de OO. O paradigma OO é inevitavelmente mais complexo do que procedimental por ser uma adição significativa ao que é oferecido por este. A falta de lambdas não é algo inerente e já foi resolvido na maioria das linguagens *mainstream* que sofriam desse problema. A injeção de dependências não é um problema inerente a OO, mas desconfio que uma solução mais definitiva dela leva a um outro paradigma (que desconheço o nome) tal como ocorre com os *crosscutting-concerns*. [continua]

Comment: @jsbueno [... continuação] E retornando à questão da herança simples e múltipla de implementação, o principal problema é que a herança de implementação leva a um acoplamento forte ao invés de fraco. Entretanto, isso é um problema inerente à herança de implementação, mas não da OO, pois ao contrário do que muitos pensam (inclusive eu pensei assim por alguns anos), a herança de implementação não é algo inerente a OO. Aliás, nem a herança de tipo é inerente a OO. A herança de tipo é inerente apenas às linguagens OO com tipagem estática, sendo dispensada quando a tipagem é dinâmica.

Comment: @VictorStafusa _"Na verdade, isso é uma crítica ao mal-uso de herança e a falta de tipos genéricos em uma linguagem fortemente tipada_". Quando é possível existir herança sem OO? Simulando em procedural? De que outras formas?

Comment: @Piovezan Na verdade, o que quis dizer é que é possível ter OO sem herança, e não o contrário. No procedural, até é possível simular-se herança simples utilizando `struct`s dentro de `struct`s e *casts*, onde o `struct` que corresponde a superclasse é o primeiro membro do `struct` da subclasse e por causa disso, ambos estão no mesmo endereço de memória. Para herança múltipla, você acaba tendo que substituir o *cast* por outra coisa mais complicada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não entendi o caso do X-Stream. Os caras criam um mapa chamado `OrderRetainingMap` e fazem ele estender `HashMap` que é justamente uma implementação que não retém ordem e depois reclamam que os métodos herdados da superclasse são incompatíveis com a intenção da classe? Cadê Liskov aí? Não entendi como isso fortalece o ponto do acoplamento forte em herança.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu vi que o problema aconteceu porque eles esperavam que `HashMap#put()` fosse chamado e em vez disso por alguma razão foi chamado um tal `HashMap#putVal()`, o que é uma quebra do contrato da classe (inserções deveriam ser feitas com `put()`). Mas ainda não entendi a relação.

Answer (score 6):

Esta resposta não é nova e sim um resumo das outras duas respostas. Não é preciso dar upvote nem nada. Serve para consolidar os argumentos contra OO e pode servir para acrescentar/corrigir o entendimento dos mesmos ou dar continuidade à discussão (na resposta do Victor cabem mais coisas, a do Maniero atingiu o limite).

### Opacidade de abstrações polimórficas

**Inerente a linguagens estáticas polimórficas**

*Victor:* Atrapalha iniciantes, que ficam perdidos tentando achar qual versão polimórfica está sendo chamada.

*Maniero:* Não é uma limitação de OO e sim de linguagens estáticas fazendo uso de polimorfismo. Prejudica a legibilidade e com isso a manutenibilidade. Adicionalmente, abstração em excesso pode ser prejudicial.

### Simulando polimorfismo em uma linguagem estruturada

**Irrelevante**

*Victor:* causa padrões (sintaxes) gambiarradas pois vai contra o suporte da linguagem.

*Maniero:* Discorda. Não há nada errado em fazer isso a não ser que haja motivo para não fazer. Coesão também tem malefícios.

*Piovezan:* Não entendi o porquê dessa crítica. Só é limitação em linguagens não projetadas para OO.

### Double-dispatch

**Pertinente**

*Victor:* ocorre quando é preciso fazer uma coisa que não é suportada pelo paradigma: escolher qual método chamar baseado no tipo de dois objetos e não um só. Soluções envolvem o padrão Visitor, introspecção/reflection ou tabelas com n x m objetos, e resultam em boa quantidade de código e complexidade para gerenciar.

*Maniero:* Concorda e acha um dos maiores problemas do paradigma. Comum acontecer quando se tenta modelar algo que não existe, quando não cabe usar OO. Quando acontece talvez um relacionamento seria mais adequado. Ocorre com frequência e é difícil entender por que acontece afinal o modelo relacional costuma ser mais fácil de entender.

### Herança múltipla de implementação

**Inerente a tipagem estática**

*Victor:* Problema do diamante. E dificulta a implementação da linguagem.

*Maniero:* Na verdade é uma reclamação com tipagem estática. Raramente as linguagens implementam todos os recursos de linguagem necessários para o adequado suporte a herança múltipla (classes abstratas, interfaces, traits, mixins, papéis, protocolos, delegações, extensões, atributos, etc.). Além disso as pessoas não entendem de ontologia e taxonomia e têm dificuldade em lidar com herança múltipla. Se elas entendem têm mais facilidade também com o paradigma modular, que é mais simples e organizado.

*Piovezan:* Rapaz, se herança múltipla precisa de todos esses recursos para funcionar bem, então é coisa do demo :P Estou contente de ficar só na herança simples, se desse jeito funciona, pra que mais?

### Herança simples de implementação

**Pertinente**

*Victor:* Herança introduz um forte acoplamento entre a superclasse e a subclasse. Subclasses são especialmente frágeis se a superclasse sofre alterações. É frequente que o comportamento da subclasse dependa de detalhes de implementação da superclasse, quebrando frente a alterações de detalhes internos desta. Uma forma de mitigar isso é preferindo composição a herança.

*Maniero:* Concorda em tudo. E o exemplo Carro e Veículo é um modelo relacional e modular, não OO.

### Crosscutting-concerns

**Pertinente em vários paradigmas, inclusive OO**

*Victor:* Logging, gerenciamento de transação, fechamento de recursos de I/O, tratamentos de erros, introduzem complexidade adicional e acidental ao programa. E normalmente são espalhados pelo código e não concentrados em um único ponto, o que dificulta bastante a manutenção. As diversas tentativas de resolver isso sempre deixaram um pouco de concerns para trás. Pensando nisso surgiu a Programação Orientada a Aspectos, que não é bem aceita porque mantém distantes o código que executa o comportamento e o que o implementa.

*Maniero:* OO também e foi muito bem aceita. Cross-cutting concerns são problemas também em outros paradigmas. São modelagens do mundo real e OOP não se dá bem com isso. Há quem negue que esse era o objetivo do paradigma. É a maior limitação do paradigma: a taxonomia precisa ser perfeita para funcionar bem, mas isso é difícil ou impossível.

### Foco em objetos e não em ações

**Mitigado / irrelevante**

*Victor:* é uma crítica dos defensores de linguagens funcionais à OO, apesar de não ser um problema inerente a OO. Tem sido mitigado em linguagens mais modernas com a introdução do conceito de lambdas, tornando-as híbridas.

*Maniero:* Discorda que as linguagens com alguns recursos funcionais se renderam ao funcional; continuam sendo imperativas. E OO não tem nada a ver com ações, OO é estruturas de dados, zero algoritmos.

### Inextensibilidade de classes

**Inerente a tipagem estática**

*Victor:* Todo mundo já quis adicionar funcionalidade a uma classe existente, e por não conseguir criou um `StringUtils`, `DateUtils`, etc. Não é problema inerente a OO, pois em linguagens dinâmicas isso se resolve através de mix-ins, porém com a desvantagem de manter afastado o código extra da classe que o inclui.

*Maniero:* Até onde sabe o paradigma puro exige que classes devam ser estendidas, mas pode haver controvérsias. OOP tende a destruir a coesão deixando junto o que é separado. A granularidade de outros paradigmas evita isso.

### Injeção de dependências

**Pertinente / mal aplicada**

*Victor:* Criar um objeto implica em fornecer dependências ao seu construtor. A cadeia de dependências pode ficar complicada (*Piovezan:* não entendo de DI então essa frase pode estar imprecisa). A solução são os frameworks de injeção de dependência, que infelizmente acrescentam complexidade aos projetos.

*Maniero:* Concorda. Modelar objetos é complicado, as pessoas aprendem DI para ajudar nos testes e depois os testes não são efetivos, ou por serem mal aplicados ou pela filosofia de qualidade do projeto não manter a consistência.

*Piovezan:* Isso foi o que entendi da resposta do Maniero, não sei se está correto.

### Maior complexidade que outros paradigmas

**Pertinente**

*Victor:* O caminho para dominar OO é mais longo e difícil que o procedimental por exemplo, e além disso as pessoas praticam e perpetuam práticas inadequadas de programação que dificultam o caminho ainda mais.

*Maniero:* Concorda em parte. Pena que as pessoas não entendem que OOP é modelar. OOP é mais útil para frameworks, em sistemas de negócios a experiência parece ser que não é tão bom assim. Usar OOP errado e usar onde não deve não entregam valor.

### Complexidade extra na representação de conceitos abstratos

**Crítica à abstração e não a OOP**

*Victor:* Enumerações de ints ou strings só são preferíveis a classes quando ocorrem em poucas partes do código, caso contrário dificultam a manutenção, ao passo que OO elimina o problema.

*Maniero:* considero a crítica válida, mas à abstração e não a OOP.

### Programação orientada a objetos tem desempenho inferior

**Pertinente quando desempenho é importante**

*Victor:* Na prática não é um problema real.

*Maniero:* Se desempenho for importante, OOP pode se mostrar lenta quando for tarde demais; trata-se de erro de projeto mas a escolha do paradigma contribui.

### Excesso de especificação sem tipos genéricos

**Pertinente / Inerente a linguagens OO com tipagem estática**

*Victor:* É uma crítica a linguagens sem tipos genéricos ou ao mau uso da herança, e não à OO.

*Maniero:* Não dá pra fazer OO em linguagens estáticas do jeito certo porque tem que usar um paradigma separado que é o da genericidade, e isso é um problema grave.

### Falta de uma definição canônica do que é orientado a objetos

**Inconclusivo**

*Victor:* Na prática existe concordância suficiente.

*Maniero:* Não. Por falta de consenso há recomendações conflitantes, como quem manda pôr tudo na classe vs. quem manda a classe só fazer uma coisa (exemplo?).

### Modelo anêmico

**Inconclusivo**

*Victor:* Modelo anêmico deliberadamente viola OO, portanto não é uma crítica válida.

*Maniero:* Modelo anêmico é um modelo modular que facilita muito a manutenção. Não é uma violação à coesão. O que importa é a responsabilidade única. 100% OOP incentiva a violar o DRY, algo que tem encontrado resistência forte ultimamente.

### Dificuldade de se escrever um compilador

**Irrelevante**

*Victor e Maniero:* Problema de quem cria a linguagem e não de quem a usa (comentário do Maniero: as linguagens estão em algum grau se afastando do paradigma).

## Pontos adicionais do Maniero

- OO não foi muito pesquisado, caso contrário a definição de OO seria canônica.
- É difícil estabelecer os limites do objetos. Em outras palavras, OO não modela a mente humana.
- A tipagem estática do Java obriga certos mecanismos a funcionar de uma forma. Isso é coberto na maior parte pela resposta do Victor.
- Tem problemas com concorrência (não coube detalhamento na resposta).
- OOP exige modelar certo, exige ontologia, que as pessoas têm dificuldade para fazer, e sempre lidamos com problemas que não conhecemos, ou repetimos o que já conhecemos. É um convite para o desastre.
- OOP inibe a criatividade, pois tem que seguir certos padrões para dar certo. Funciona para coisas recorrentes, modelar o que já se sabe modelar.
- Ocultar (encapsular) estado é a pior opção possível em comparação a, por exemplo, isolá-lo.
- Se pesquisar OOP/OOD + flaw/bad/sucks/evil/misuse/etc. encontrará muitos argumentos que fazem sentido.
- Muitos excelentes programadores batem em OOP e têm bons argumentos para isso.
- Pessoas estão se distanciando de OOP. Distanciar não é abandonar, é usar onde precisa.
- OOP na sua forma pura (sem outros mecanismos que cubram as deficiências do paradigma) exige fazer coisas pouco pragmáticas e códigos pouco eficientes.
- Se aplica a 1%, talvez 10% dos casos e não a 100% como as pessoas pensam. Em sistemas de negócios não é tão benéfica.
- Se seguir todas as várias regras, pode dar certo.

Comment: Não seria melhor transformar isso aqui, esse compêndio com os melhores momentos, em uma publicação wiki da comunidade?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado A vantagem maior é que usuários precisariam ter somente 100 pontos e não 2000 para editar a resposta. Os maiores interessados em editá-la já têm essa pontuação e podem editá-la sem problemas. Fora isso não vejo objeção. Vou deixar a cargo de um moderador a decisão.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Minha intenção ao criá-la foi para consolidar os argumentos de uma discussão que já ocorre na pergunta. Quem não respondeu e tem argumentos novos pode muito bem criar uma nova resposta.

Comment: @Piovezan agora que vi isso. Merece voto sim. Só mudo para CW se pedir. Vamos lá aos pontos que acho que merece comentário: O tempo todo fazemos herança múltipla de subtipo e até um pouco de comportamento, raramente de estado. De fato é raro ter dois estados que podem juntos formar um novo. C++ tem só um mecanismo para tudo, e é uma das maiores bombas que já criaram em linguagens. Melhor ter vários mecanismos. Em linguagens dinâmicas tem um só também e até que funciona se desconsiderar o problema de explodir na sua cara em tempo de execução.

Comment: Sobre os tipos genéricos foi uma ironia.  Então seu entendimento não considerou isto. O que eu quis dizer é que a defesa que OO certo é usar o paradigma de genericidade então não dá para fazer OO em linguagens estáticas do jeito certo. Para resolver o problema citado tem que abandonar o paradigma, portanto é um problema grave. É um crítica altamente pertinente porque OO mesmo tem os problemas que a crítica aponta. Eu quase negativei a resposta do Victor por causa disto. Está muito errado. A crítica se aplica porque só se resolve com outro paradigma.

Comment: E eu já tinha percebido que as pessoas não entendem que genericidade não faz parte de OO. Notamos como a falta de definição formal gera muito opinião. É bom ressaltar sobre o modelo anêmico que minha crítica é que OOP força fazer coisas ruins para manutenção, o modelo anêmico bem aplicado ajuda resolver isto, fugindo mesmo do que OOP, por isso minha crítica geral ao paradigma, as soluções para problemas reais sempre exigem sair dele.

Comment: Alguns pontos são enormes simplificações das simplificações que eu já tinha feito, e acho que o Victor também, portanto considerem isto para formar uma opinião. E por último não estou dizendo que outros paradigmas são ótimos, apenas que não tem os problemas de OOP e que muitas vezes são mais fáceis de lidar. Mas para certos problemas as suas limitações são piores que OOP. Não estou descendo a lenha no paradigma, apenas fazendo crítica onde cabe. Minha crítica maior é o abuso e o uso sem completo entendimento do que é e como o paradigma pode ser benéfico.

Comment: Sobre os tipos genéricos, substituí a ironia pelo argumento em si; e sobre a definição canônica do paradigma requisitei um exemplo, a meu ver necessário para fortalecer o argumento.