# O que é relacionamento e modelo relacional fora do contexto de banco de dados?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelo-relacional

O que seriam **relacionamento** e **modelo relacional** nos contextos abaixo (retirados [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277179/357))?

Contexto 1:

> Double-dispatch
>
> *Maniero:* Concordo e acho *[a falta de suporte a double-dispatch ou a visão de que é preciso aplicar double-dispatch]* um dos maiores problemas do mecanismo todo. Suficiente para desqualificar o uso onde não deve.
>
> É um exemplo abstrato demais para eu afirmar, mas é muito comum esse problema surgir quando se tenta modelar algo que não existe de fato, quando se tenta usar OOP onde não cabe, talvez um **relacionamento** seria mais adequado.
>
> Minha percepção é que isto ocorre demais no uso de OOP.
>
> Aí vem o problema que eu falo, a pessoa fica tão cega em usar OOP para tudo que ela consegue ignorar que tem meios mais fácil de resolver o problema. O **modelo relacional** costuma ser mais fácil para as pessoas entenderem.

**EDIT 1:** A resposta do @prmottajr (apagada) quase matou a questão ao citar relacionamento entre entidades e me fazer lembrar que relacionamento pode estar se referindo a **associações** no modelo de domínio. Mas a pergunta na verdade quer saber como os termos se aplicam nos contextos citados, então é preciso um pouco mais de detalhamento. No caso do contexto acima, o que não tenho claro é como seria uma associação assim no diagrama de classes e como isso se traduziria em código.

Contexto 2:

> Herança simples de implementação
>
> *Victor:* A herança pode ser quase sempre substituída por composição. Um objeto na memória é composto por vários campos que correspondem a outros objetos (ou a valores primitivos/built-in). Por exemplo, um objeto da classe `Veiculo` seria representado por uma sequência de dados `placa`, `proprietário`, `tipo-de-combustível`. Um objeto do tipo `Carro` (subclasse de `Veiculo`) seria representado por `placa`, `proprietário`, `tipo-de-combustível`, `cor`, `modelo`, `marca`. Observe que isso é quase o equivalente a fazer com que a estrutura da subclasse fosse `Veiculo`, `cor`, `modelo`, `marca`. Ou seja, ao usar composição no lugar de herança, chega-se a uma estrutura com os mesmos dados, mas a **subclasse** é mais flexível quanto ao que ela pode encapsular da superclasse e como.
>
> *Maniero:* Concordo 100%, em especial a última frase do 1º parágrafo. E isto é um **modelo relacional** e modular e não OO.

**EDIT 2:** Entendi que estamos falando de composição, que é um tipo de associação, e que a palavra "subclasse" que acabei de negritar na citação acima na verdade seria "composição". O que falta entender é:

a) o exemplo é apenas ilustrativo, não se está recomendando uma modelagem em que um Carro seja composto por um Veículo, está? (óbvio que não, acho que nem deveria estar perguntando isso, mas é só para deixar claro);

b) em OOA&D existe o diagrama de classes conceitual e o diagrama de classes do projeto. Ao se falar "Carro contém Veículo" estamos no conceitual e ao se falar "Carro herda de Veículo" ou "Carro é composto por Veículo" estamos no projeto. Quanto estamos no conceitual faz sentido então a afirmação de que se trata de modelo relacional e que isso não é OO. Já no projeto estamos mapeando do conceitual para o OO e nesse caso penso que não faz sentido fazer essa afirmação. Estou correto? Nesse caso eu não entendi o impacto dessa afirmação, ou seja, o impacto de frisar *"e isto é um modelo relacional e não OO"*.

Também tenho dúvida de por que é um modelo modular, mas acho melhor deixar para outra pergunta para não sair do escopo desta, a não ser que a resposta seja simples.

P.S.: Peço desculpas pelo meu estilo de escrita ser muito convoluto, depois de um tempo sem ler a pergunta dá pra perceber isso.